# Functions accepting C/C++ array types

Tags: c++, strong-typing

It seems like g++ ignores difference in array sizes when passing arrays as arguments. I.e., the following compiles with no warnings even with `-Wall`.

```
void getarray(int a[500])
{
    a[0] = 1;
}

int main()
{
    int aaa[100];
    getarray(aaa);
}
```

Now, I understand the underlying model of passing a pointer and obviously I could just define the function as `getarray(int *a)`. I expected, however, that gcc will at least issue a warning when I specified the array sizes explicitly.

Is there any way around this limitation? (I guest boost::array is one solution but I have so much old code using c-style array which got promoted to C++...)

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328223/sizeof-array-passed-as-parameter

Comment: @Richard: the answer to that question contains the clue to this one.  The question however is different.  This one is about type preservation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Arrays are passed as a pointer to their first argument. If the size is important, you must declare the function as `void getarray(int (&a)[500]);`

The C idiom is to pass the size of the array like this: void getarray(int a[], int size);
The C++ idiom is to use std::vector (or std::tr1::array more recently).

Comment: Using int a[500] just passes a pointer to an int. Using int(&a)[500] passes a reference to an array of 500 elements. They are different types and the compiler sees the mismatch. By the way, by using int(&a)[500] you can't pass an array allocated with new int[500] any more!

Comment: Great! A useful technique. The actual generated code is identical as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3):

I second [what rpg said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372186/functions-accepting-c-c-array-types/1372194#1372194). However, in case you want to call the function with arrays of any size, you could use a template to do that:

```
template< std::size_t N>
void getarray(int (&a)[N])
```

Comment: +1, this can be a useful approach, but be aware that you can no longer call this function with a plain `int *`!

Comment: @j_random_hacker: I actually see this as an advantage.