# What do these struct and typedef definitions mean?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I have the following code, which works fine and has been in use for a quite a while now... but I have no idea what it means.

```
struct event_param
{
    int task:3;
    int param1;
    int param2;
};

#define SV_DRIVER_EVENTS_MASK_SIZE (SV_DRIVER_EVENT_LAST*sizeof(struct event_param))
typedef struct event_param driver_event_mask[SV_DRIVER_EVENTS_MASK_SIZE];
typedef driver_event_mask DriverEventMask;
```

- What does `driver_event_mask` represent?
- Why is there `sizeof(struct event_param)` inside the array?

Comment: what was your actual question?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

*how to typedef strcuts array in c?*

How to define is already shown in your question, for why refer below:-

> If a typedef name denotes a variable length array type, the length of
>   the array is fixed at the time the typedef name is defined, not each
>   time it is used:

*what does `DriverEventMask` represents*

> DriverEventMask represent struct event_param

*why there are* `sizeof(struct event_param)`

> So that SV_DRIVER_EVENTS_MASK_SIZE  will represent the size of struct
>   event_param. This struct contain bit fields and the way it is arranged
>   is not sure until we know if there are any compiler directives to
>   avoid padding.

Comment: Compiler **will** know the size of structure, won't it? So multiplying by `sizeof()` here is unnecessary.

Comment: No, you dont know for what purpose SV_DRIVER_EVENTS_MASK_SIZE is being defined.So using sizeof tells compiler to evaluate size.

Comment: Ok, so `SV_DRIVER_EVENT_LAST*sizeof(struct event_param)` is the expected size of the array in *bytes*, is it not? So you claim that if you typedef an array, you have to specify its size in bytes, rather than number of items in the array?

Comment: I think this is not the case, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416898/typedefing-an-array-vs-using-a-struct-in-c

Comment: That doesn't mean you have to allocate twelve times the memory. I doubt that the padding will change during the program execution.

Comment: The quotation refers to the case where the array length typedef includes an actual variable, which is not the case. sizeof(whatever) is not a variable.

Answer (score 1):

The `:3` thing represents a [bit field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field). I'm not sure it matters much, though, since `sizeof(struct event_param)` will still almost certainly be 12 bytes, I think.

So what happens here is that an array of `SV_DRIVER_EVENT_LAST` of `event_param` structures is created. But I would also expect that the `sizeof(struct event_param)` is not necessary here -- the length of an array is defined in the number of units it contains, not in bytes.

**1.** `driver_event_mask` is just what it says. A type to represent an array of SV_DRIVER_EVENTS_MASK_SIZE struct event_param items.

**2.** `sizeof(struct event_param)` is not needed here, but doesn't hurt (i.e. won't cause bugs) since it just means you allocate about 12 times as much memory as you actually need.

Comment: what does this line meens  typedef struct event_param driver_event_mask[SV_DRIVER_EVENTS_MASK_SIZE]; ??

Comment: Just what it says. Let type `driver_event_mask` represent an array of `SV_DRIVER_EVENTS_MASK_SIZE` `struct event_param` items.

Comment: isnt it supposed to be the other way ? i meen typedef struct event_param[32] driver_event_mask ?

Comment: @shd check the function typedefs, those also look strange in terms of ordering.