# Sizeof doesn't return the true size of variable in C

Tags: c, sizeof

Consider the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(char string[]){
 printf("%s:%d\n",string,sizeof(string));
}

int main(){
 char string[] = "Hello World";
 print(string);
}
```

and the output is

```
Hello World:4
```

So what's wrong with that ?

Comment: What are you expecting as output?

Comment: I recommend using `std::string`. It is much easier to work with. The length would be `str.size()`.

Comment: std::string is C++ rather than C

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sizeof array passed as parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328223/sizeof-array-passed-as-parameter)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does return the true size of the "variable" (really, the parameter to the function). The problem is that this is not of the type you think it is.

`char string[]`, as a parameter to a function, is equivalent to `char* string`. You get a result of `4` because that is the size, on your system, of a `char*`.

Please read more here: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html

Answer (score 3):

It is the size of the char pointer, not the length of the string.

Use strlen from string.h to get the string length.

Comment: That's OK if you know the string is NUL terminated. In this application, it is. But generally, a string is just a character array

Comment: @Paul: Generally a "string" is used to mean a NTBS in the context of C. A character array is just a character array.

Comment: OK, I may retract generally (but there was a SO question yesterday that was about a mistaken assumption that character arrays could be assumed to be terminated, so I think it's worth pointing out)

Comment: @Paul: I don't deny that sometimes this convention goes wrong :-). I agree that people have to be careful and should be warned. Normally for function parameters I'd refer to a required-to-be-nul-terminated array of chars as a "string", and a not-necessarily-terminated array as a "buffer" or just "array".

Answer (score 1):

`string` is a pointer and its size is 4. You need `strlen` probably.

Comment: ... in the definition of `print`. In `main`, `string` is the name of an array.

Answer (score 1):

a array will change into a pointer as parameter of function in ANSI C.

Answer (score 1):

Except when it is an operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an array expression will have its type implicitly converted ("decay") from "N-element array of T" to "pointer to T" and its value will be the address of the first element in the array ([n1256](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), 6.3.2.1/3).

The *object* `string` in `main` is a 12-element array of `char`.  In the call to `print` in `main`, the type of the *expression* `string` is converted from `char [12]` to `char *`.  Therefore, the `print` function receives a pointer value, not an array.  In the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[]` and `T a[N]` are both synonymous with `T *`; note that this is *only* true for function parameter declarations (this is one of C's bigger misfeatures IMO).

Thus, the `print` function is working with a pointer type, not an array type, so `sizeof string` returns the size of a `char *`, not the size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

A string in c is just an array of characters. It isn't necessarily NUL terminated (although in your case it is). There is no way for the function to know how long the string is that's passed to it - it's just given the address of the string as a pointer.

"String" is that pointer and on your machine (a 32 bit machine) it takes 4 bytes to store a pointer. So sizeof(string) is 4

Comment: By definition, a string in C *must* be 0-terminated (7.1.1).  If a sequence of `char` isn't 0-terminated, then it isn't a string.

Comment: That just moves the goalposts sideways a bit. Is char [] string as a parameter defining a string, or not? In practice, it's up to the app.

Comment: Only if the sequence that it points to is 0-terminated.  All strings are sequences of characters, but not all sequences of characters are strings.  If `string` had been initialized as `{'H','e','l','l','o',' ','W','o','r','l','d'}`, then the output of `print` would be indeterminate; it will print "Hello World" followed by some amount of junk until it happens to see a 0-valued character.

Answer (score 0):

You asked the systems for the sizeof(the address to the begining of a character array), string is an object, to get information about it's lenght out you have to ask it through the correct OO interface.

In the case of std::string the member function string.length(), will return the number of characters stored by the string object.

Answer (score -2):

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Cpp/Data-Type/StringSizeOf.htm
see here it has same output as yours...and find what ur doing wrong

Comment: my given link is about C++ not C...so what's the problem MAN...although he tagged his question as C

Comment: Exactly. He tagged his question as C. So knowing how sizeof behaves in C++ isn't going to be very helpful