# Why does sizeof return different values for same string in C?

Tags: c, string, unix, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sizeof doesn't return the true size of variable in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366600/sizeof-doesnt-return-the-true-size-of-variable-in-c)
>   [C -> sizeof string is always 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941142/c-sizeof-string-is-always-8)

Sizeof prints out 6 for:

```
printf("%d\n", sizeof("abcde"));
```

But it prints out 4 for:

```
char* str = "abcde";
printf("%d\n", sizeof(str));
```

Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The string literal `"abcde"` is a character *array*.  It is 6 bytes long, including the null terminator.

A variable of type `char*` is a *pointer* to a character.  Its size is the size of a pointer, which on 32-bit systems is 4 bytes.  `sizeof` is a compile time operation<sup>†</sup>, so it only looks at the variable's static type, which in this case is `char*`.  It has no idea what's being pointed to.

† Except in the case of variable-length arrays, a feature introduced in the C99 language standard

Answer (score 2):

First example, `sizeof()` return the **length of the plain string**.
Second example, `sizeof()` return the **size of the pointer** -> 32bits so 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Because here

```
printf("%d\n", sizeof("abcde"));
```

is a string, with considering NULL its 6 byte long.

and

```
char* str = "abcde";
printf("%d\n", sizeof(str));
```

is a pointer that requires 32bits hence 4 bytes :-)