# why sizeof(a pointer) returns incorrect value?

Tags: c, string, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sizeof string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392200/sizeof-string-literal)

On my windows7 mingw environment, I tried this:

```
char str[] = "hello";
```

The value of `sizeof(str)` is 6, not 4 or 8.

How can this happen?

Comment: This one comes up quite often...

Comment: why do you think it should be 4 or 8?

Comment: However, if i have a function which accepts an array of char, when i pass the str to it,the value of sizeof is 4...

Comment: @hata That's because you are sending a *pointer* to the function (ie the address of the array)

Comment: @Levon No, the address of the first element of the array. Same numeric value, different type (and hence quite different pointer arithmetic, among other things).

Comment: @delnan yes, you are right of course .. increment etc of the pointer in the function will vary based on the type of array elements, but I don't see how this does not equal the address (ie start) of the array.

Comment: @Levon As I also said, the numeric value of the pointer will be the same, but it's certainly not the same *pointer* (after all, it behaves quite differently for many important operations on pointers), so I'd be wary to say it's the same address due to the two concepts being often (and in many other cases, without ill effect) conflated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof(str)` returns the number of bytes in the string which includes the terminating null character. I.e., `"hello\0"` makes for 6 bytes in your *array*.

If instead you had had

```
char* str = "hello";
```

then `sizeof(str)` would have returned the number of bytes in the *pointer* `str` (4 for 32-bit systems).

You may find this SO question [Why does sizeof return different values for same string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644267/why-does-sizeof-return-different-values-for-same-string-in-c) of interest.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `str` is an array of `chars`. `sizeof(array)` will tell you the number of bytes that the array occupies, and since `str` is an array of `chars`, each element is only 1 byte, including the null terminating character, for 6 bytes.

You can get the number of *elements* in an array using: `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])`, and so this could be more explicitly written: `sizeof(str)/sizeof(str[0])`, but if `str` is an array of `char` then this is equivalent to just `sizeof(str)`.

Note that this **isn't** generally applicable to C strings, for the length of a string, use `strlen`. For instance:

```
char *str = "hello";
sizeof(str);  // returns 4, since str is declared as char*, not char[]
```

Answer (score 2):

The "sizeof()" operator returns the number of bytes.  In the case of your string, it happens to be 6 (5 characters plus the null byte).  For a 6 element integer array, it's 24 (at least on my 32-bit Linux system).  And for a pointer, it will be 4 (again, for a 32-bit system).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char str[] = "Hello";
  char *s = "Hello";
  int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
  printf ("sizeof (str)=%d, sizeof(s)=%d, sizseof(a)=%d\n",
    sizeof (str), sizeof(s), sizeof(a));
  return 0;
}
```

RESULT:

```
sizeof (str)=6, sizeof(s)=4, sizeof(a)=24
```