# char* passed into function is shortened to four characters

Tags: c++, arrays, parameter-passing, sizeof

```
void myfunc(char* passedArray)
{
    cout << sizeof(passedArray) << endl; // prints 4
}

int main(void)
{
    char charArray[] = "abcdefghiklmop";

    cout << sizeof(charArray) << endl; // prints 15
    myfunc(charArray);
    cout << sizeof(charArray) << endl; // prints 15
}
```

I believe it should still print 15 inside that function...

Comment: this has been asked sooo many times. Have you even tried googling it?

Comment: YES, thoroughly. It isn't on SO, and I couldn't find it on any forum.

Comment: you passed in a pointer for a parameter and `sizeof(char*)==4` holds for your platform by chance. There is basically no way to determine the length of the array from a pointer to the first element.

Comment: Then not only this question is a fail, your googling skills seem lacking too. stackoverflow.com/questions/4941142/c-sizeof-string-is-always-8/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392200/sizeof-string-literal/1392228#1392228 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919369/why-sizeofa-pointer-returns-incorrect-value http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392200/sizeof-string-literal

Comment: I recommend that next time anyone posts with `c++` `array` `sizeof` related topic, show this list of posts before they get to click "post".

Comment: @phoeagon, you mean like the list of possible duplicates that is already displayed when you type in a question!?

Comment: NONE of those questions answered my question concisely, but sorry if I've offended the SO crowd. New to C/++ and had no reason to expect it would be converted to a pointer.

Comment: @storyteller Yeah, but for this particular question (and some others that have been asked sooooooo many times), make the author click on at least one of the link or use some other means of extra notification...

Comment: I checked the similar answers, folks. They didn't answer my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a classic problem with pointers and arrays. The issue is that arrays decay to pointers, as you can see. Pointer types hold *no* metadata about the data it points to except for the size of the pointed to type. All other metadata, such as array length is lost.

The issue therefore is that you have called `myfunc` with a *pointer* to the array; all metadata about the array is then invisible to the `myfunc` function. This then triggers a subtle difference in the `sizeof` operator, which is that when it is applied to a pointer, it gives the size of the pointer type, not the length of the array. When applied to an array however, it gives the length of the array, as you can see in the `main` function.

Short fix, use `strlen` instead.

Comment: All this is a nice explination of a different issue.  He _has_ declared _passedArray_ as a pointer, so there's no issue of decay at the point where he's using `sizeof`.  And the solution is not to use `strlen`, but `std::string`.

Comment: No, it's the same issue because he's calling `sizeof` on a pointer, I'm just trying to articulate why this is the issue. My solution of "use `strlen` instead" comes simply from my pure C background, so yes, `std::string` is another valid fix. The issue of decay still appears when he is implicitly converting an array to a pointer when calling the function.

Comment: Exactly.  He's using `sizeof` on an object which is declared and defined as a pointer.  There's no issue of decay surrounding the `sizeof`.  (If he were asking how he could pass an array to a function declared to take a pointer, or if he'd declared `myfunc` to take an array, your answer would be appropriate.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Fair enough, I take your point there. I see this a lot though when people are learning C, they expect `sizeof` to be a run-time function which gives the size of whatever they throw at it, including the length of arrays. Typically, it's because they don't realise the actual differences between pointers and arrays properly. I was just trying to give an explanation that showed he was passing said array as a pointer, and the effects of doing so while also trying to articulate that `sizeof(ptr)` returns the size of the pointer, not the array as he expected.

Comment: I also appreciate that is looks flaming obvious when you look over the code, but new programmers *do* end up getting locked in a loop that sizeof in a foreign function on a passed array will do exactly the same as expected when called on the array. Sometimes it just takes the extra kick for the "oh...yeah." moment.

Comment: I appreciate the fact that new programmers get confused, especially because there seem to be sites that claim that pointers and arrays are the same thing.  And he does seem to suffer a little from this.  But in that case, you should probably start out by insisting on the fact that they are different.  (And that you cannot pass an array to a function, and ...  You could end up with a book.  That's why I alway say: just use `std::string`.)

Comment: That's a good point, looking back I should have made the clear distinction within `myfunc`, the array had decayed to a pointer and was a completely different type. It is basically what I was trying to articulate throughout though, and explain the difference between `sizeof` on a pointer and array. Finally, yeah, my pure C background tends to burn me on C++ questions like that :P

Answer (score 4):

Although you defined your array as `char charArray[]`, when you pass it to your function that takes `char*`, the `charArray` is being converted into the pointer to the first element, thus when you call `sizeof` in the body of your function, it prints the size of the pointer (which is 4 bytes on 32bit machines) as expected.

[Even if your function took `char passedArray[]` as an argument](http://ideone.com/4icIFA), original `charArray` would be decayed into pointer to the first element and ability to retrieve the size of this array by calling `sizeof` would be lost. (see [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)).

So you can call [`strlen()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) to retrieve the size of this C-style string but since you are writing C++ code then the most reasonable solution is to use [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) instead of C-style strings.

Comment: +1 for the "array decaying" link

Answer (score 4):

First, what do you expect?  You've defined `passedArray` to be
a pointer, so `sizeof(passedArray)` will return the size of
a pointer on your machine.  What else could it do?  I could
understand some confusion if your function was:

```
void myFunc( char passedArray[15] )
```

A reasonable person could expect `sizeof(passedArray)` to be 15
in this case (but he'd be wrong, because when used as
a parameter, and array is converted by the compiler into
a pointer, and this definition is exactly the same as yours).

The answer to all this is to use `std::string`:

```
void
myFunc( std::string const& passedValue )
{
    std::cout << passedValue.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Unlike `char[]`, `std::string` actually works.  C style arrays,
whether used as strings or not, are broken, and should only be
used in a very limited set of cases, mostly related to objects
with static lifetime and order of initialization issues.

Comment: relatively new to C/++, had no reason to expect it would be converted to a pointer. I'm debugging an old piece of code that was using sizeof() on a pointer expecting an array.

Comment: @NicholasPickering The function was defines `myFunc( char* )`.  `char*` is a pointer.  Period.  There's no implicit conversion or anything involved in `myFunc`.  (There's an implicit conversion at the call site, of course.  But that's a different issue.)  And regardless of how new you are to C++ (there's no such thing as C/C++), if you define a type `X`, why would you expect a type `Y`.  (In fact, as I point out, there is one such case.  But it doesn't occur in your program.)

Comment: I was implying I was new to both, not that the program is using both. I would expect that probably because I really only have experience in weakly typed languages.

Answer (score 2):

Use `strlen()`, not `sizeof()`, to get the length of your string.

In C, a string is just a zero-terminated character array. There is no special `String` type in C. `strlen()` is a function which counts the number of characters until the terminating zero byte.

`sizeof()` is an operator which can be used to determine the size of a variable or of a datatype. In your case, `sizeof()` returns the size of the `char*` pointer (which seems to be 4 bytes on your platform).

Comment: then what does sizeof() do? why does it differ from within main to within the function?

Comment: @NicholasPickering `sizeof` returns the size of the object which is its argument.  You're argument has type `char*`, so it returns the size of a `char*`.  It gives different results in `main` because you've applied it to a different object.

Comment: He's marked the posting C++, and is using `std::cout`, so what C does is more or less irrelevant.  In C++, a string is a class type defined in the standard library, and until you're an expert, that's really all you should be using.

Comment: This code is old. I'm debugging it. The original developer used `sizeof`, when he should of used any of the other code you've all suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the function, this

```
cout << sizeof(passedArray) << endl;
```

is printing the size of a `passedArray`, which is a`char*`. A pointer is size 4 on your platform. If you pass a pointer to a function, the function has no way of knowing that it is pointing to the first element of a fixed size array. If you want the size of a fixed array, then pass an array, not a pointer:

```
template< class T, size_t N >
void myfunc( const T (&passedArray)[N] )
{
  std::cout << N << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(char*)` gives the size of the pointer, not of the pointed-to string.

What you really want is `strlen`.

The reason why it gives the string size in `main()` is because it's defined as a `char[]` (an array which size is known at compile-time) not a `char*`.

Comment: What he really wants is `std::string`, not `strlen`.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(passedArray)` returns size of the pointer `passedArray`, which is of type `char *`, and in your system, apparently 4 bytes.

use `strlen` instead, or rather, use `std::string`