# Sizeof() on a C++ array works in one function, but not in the other

Tags: c++, arrays, sizeof

I'm trying to learn more about arrays since I'm new to programming. So I was playing with different parts of code and was trying to learn about three things, `sizeof()`. How do I find the length of an array, and also how do I put arrays into functions (as a parameter)?

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void arrayprint(int inarray[])
{
    for (int n_i = 0 ; n_i < (sizeof(inarray) / sizeof(int)) ; n_i++)
    {
        cout << inarray[n_i] << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n_array[5];
    for (int n_i = 0 ; n_i < (sizeof(n_array) / sizeof(int)) ; n_i++ )
    {
        cin >> n_array[n_i];
    }
    arrayprint(n_array);
    return 0;
}
```

It seems the `sizeof(inarray) / sizeof(int)` works in the main function, but not in the arrayprint function. In the array print function, it evaluates to 1, while in main it evaluates to 5. Why?

So I guess what I want to know is how they are different? And why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sizeof array passed as parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328223/sizeof-array-passed-as-parameter)

Comment: There are many duplicates of this question, you can search SO or in google for "array decay" in C++

Comment: You may find information mentioned here useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328223/sizeof-array-passed-as-parameter

Basically, I would recommend to you to take a look at STL containers, especially vector, which is the preferred way to work with arrays in C++ programs

Comment: [related FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
void arrayprint(int inarray[])
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
void arrayprint(int *inarray)
```

So you are getting the size of an int pointer on your machine. Even if your question is about C++ and your function looks a bit different, it boils down to this [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryparmsize.html) entry.

So, inside `main` `n_array` is actually a true honest array. But when passed to a function, it "decays" into a pointer. And there's no way to know the real size. All you can do is pass additional arguments to your function.

```
void arrayprint(int inarray[], int len)
{
    for (int n_i = 0 ; n_i < len; n_i++)
    /* .... */
```

And call it like this:

```
arrayprint(n_array, sizeof(n_array) / sizeof(n_array[0]));
```

Of course, the *real* solution would be to use `vector`s since you're using C++. But I wouldn't know much about C++.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to make this work as I intended? Thanks!

Comment: Alright, good explanation!! Thanks! Although it bites that I have to declare the extra variable.

Comment: @Samuraisoulification It's good to understand this; it's better to use proper containers.

Comment: What do you mean by proper containers and vectors? Are those more advanced topics?

Answer (score 1):

What you've encountered was array-to-pointer conversion, a C language feature inherited by C++. There's a detailed C++-faq post about this: [How do I use arrays in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Since you're using C++, you could pass the array by reference:

```
template<size_t N>
void arrayprint(int (&inarray)[N])
{
    for (int n_i = 0 ; n_i < (sizeof(inarray) / sizeof(int)) ; n_i++)
        cout << inarray[n_i] << endl;
}
```

although in that case the sizeof calculation is redundant:

```
template<size_t N>
void arrayprint(int (&inarray)[N])
{
    for (size_t n_i = 0 ; n_i < N ; n_i++)
        cout << inarray[n_i] << '\n';
}
```

And, as already mentioned, if your goal is not specifically to pass a C array to a function, but to pass a container or a sequence of values, consider using `std::vector` and other containers and/or iterators.

Comment: K, what does the template<size_t N> do?

Comment: @Samuraisoulification http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c/4810672#4810672

Answer (score 1):

In `main()` your `n_array` is an array. When you take `sizeof(n_array)` you are getting the size of the array, in bytes. To be precise, you are getting the size such that sizeof(char) is identically equal to one. On most modern computers nowadays that is a byte.

**An array is not a pointer.** However, when you pass an array to some function what is passed is the address of the zeroth element of the array. The array degrades into a pointer. So your `arrayprint()` would be better prototyped as `void arrayprint(int* inarray)`. When you take `sizeof(inarray)` you aren't computing the size of `n_array` in `main()`. You are computing the size of a pointer.