# Determining the quantity of elements in a C array

Tags: c++, arrays

When print_array is called, the size of the int array[] parameter (count) isn't what was expected.  It seems sizeof is **not** returning the size of the entire array which would be 5*sizeof(int) = 20.

```
namespace Util
{
   void print_array(int array[])
   {
      size_t count = (sizeof array)/(sizeof array[0]);
      cout << count;
      // int count = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
      // for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) cout << array[i];
   }
}


int array_test[5]={2,1,5,4,3};
Util::print_array(array_test);
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a pretty annoying case in C and C++. It should mean to pass a copy of the array by value, but instead there are special rules that mean it's just like void print_array(int * const array); Also annoying, functions are explicitly forbidden from returning arrays by value even though C otherwise has the syntax: int f()[10]; In C++11 this is all fixed by using std::array.

Comment: Your code is valid C++, and not valid C. The expression "C array", in a C++ context, is not very meaningful; maybe in a few years "array" in a C++ context will mean an instance of `std::array` by default, so that "C array" would make sense, but that isn't the case yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`int array[]` here becomes `int* array`, and `sizeof(array)` returns the same thing `sizeof(int*)`. You need to pass an array by reference to avoid that.

```
template <size_t N>
void print_array(int (&array)[N]) {
    std::cout << N;
}

int array[] = { 2, 1, 5, 4, 3 };
print_array(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

Read this: it says the way to fix this, but for a quick description:

[When a function has a specific-size array parameter, why is it replaced with a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328223/sizeof-array-passed-as-parameter)

Using sizeof(array) will work in the scope that the array is statically defined in. When you pass it into a function though the type gets converted into a pointer to the array element type.  In your case, when you're in print_array it is an int*.  So, your sizeof in in the function will be the size of a pointer on your system (likely 32 or 64 bits).

You can get around this with some fancy syntax like so (from the link above):

> If you want that the array type is preserved, you should pass in a
>   reference to the array:

```
void foo ( int(&array)[5] );
```

but I'd say just pass the size in as well as another parameter, its more readable.

Comment: Pass by reference, pointer, and by value are the three primary constructs for passing information to fuction.  By value creates a copy, by reference references the entire object, and by pointer points the first address

Comment: Was there an issue related to this in the solution?

Answer (score 1):

As this array is implemented as a thin overlay on pointers, the variable you have is just a pointer, so sizeof will return the size of your pointer.

The only way to know the length of an array is to place a terminating object, as the null character in C strings.

There is no other way to determine the size of an array if you only have a pointer to it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trick: you can take a *reference* to an array of fixed size. You can use this to template-deduce the size.

```
#include <iostream>

char a [22];
char b [33];

void foo (char *, size_t size)
{
    std :: cout << size << "\n";
}

template <size_t N>
void foo (char (&x) [N])
{
    foo (x, N);
}

int main () {
    foo (a);
    foo (b);
}
```

This prints `22\n33\n`

Answer (score 0):

`void print_array( int array[] )` is synonymous with `void print_array( int *array )`. No size information is passed when the function call is made, so `sizeof` doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0):

All the following declarations are exactly same:

```
void print_array(int array[]);
void print_array(int array[10]);
void print_array(int array[200]);
void print_array(int array[1000]);
void print_array(int *array);
```

That means, `sizeof(array)` would return the value of `sizeof(int*)`, in all above cases, even in those where you use integers (they're ignored by the compiler, in fact).

However, all the following are different from each other, and co-exist in a program, at the same time:

```
void print_array(int (&array)[10]);
void print_array(int (&array)[200]);
void print_array(int (&array)[1000]);

int a[10], b[200], c[1000], d[999];
print_array(a); //ok - calls the first function
print_array(b); //ok - calls the second function
print_array(c); //ok - calls the third function
print_array(d); //error - no function accepts int array of size 999
```

Answer (score 0):

For an algorithm like this, I like to use iterators, then you can do what you want... e.g.

```
template <typename Iterator>
void print(Interator begin, Iterator end)
{
  std::cout << "size: " << std::distance(begin, end) << std::endl;
  std::copy(begin, end, std::ostream_iterator<std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type>(std::cout, ", "));
}
```

to call

```
print(a, a + 5); // can calculate end using the sizeof() stuff...
```

Answer (score 0):

just an addition to all the answers already posted:

if you want to use an array which is more comfortable (like an ArrayList in java for instance) then just use the [stl-vector container](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) which is also able to return its `size`