# Error When Passing String array to function in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, function

Hi guys I've some errors when passing some strings of array in C++, do you know what's wrong with this code guys?, Thankyou

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void showData(string data[]);

int main()
{

    string namaMahasiswa[] = {"Nico", "Yonathan", "Andre", "Ratu"};

    enum option{ SHOW = 5 };

    switch (5)
    {
    case SHOW:
        showData(namaMahasiswa);
        break;
    }
}

void showData(string data[])
{
    for (int z = 0; z < sizeof(data) / sizeof(*data); z++)
    {
        cout << data[z] << endl;
    }
}
```

This is the error :

```
'int main()':
index.cpp:61:18: error: could not convert '(std::string*)(& namaMahasiswa)' from 'std::string*' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*'} to 'std::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'}
   61 |         showData(namaMahasiswa);
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                  |
      |                  std::string* {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*}

In function 'void showData(std::string*)':
index.cpp:83:36: warning: 'sizeof' on array function parameter 'data' will return size of 'std::string*' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*'} [-Wsizeof-array-argument]
   83 |     for (int z = 0; z < sizeof(data) / sizeof(*data); z++)

index.cpp:80:22: note: declared here
   80 | void showData(string data[])
```

So it means we can't pass string array to a function like that or maybe I've to use some char?

Comment: What is `sizeof(data) / sizeof(*data)` supposed to accomplish?

Comment: It means like data.length, or to count the length from the array

Comment: Can't reproduce your error once I add the appropriate namespace.  And see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493281/c-sizeof-a-passed-array, since your size trick won't work.

Comment: The code you have posted is clearly not the code generating the error message. Form a [mre] and post it together with the error message it produces, both _verbatim_.

Comment: @NicoA.L. A `string[]` parameter is actually a decayed `string*` pointer. [You can't use the `sizeof` trick on such a parameter to get its length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443957/). You will have to pass the array's length as a separate parameter. Or pass the array by reference instead of pointer. Or use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When passing an array to a function in C++, why won't sizeof() work the same as in the main function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36525798/when-passing-an-array-to-a-function-in-c-why-wont-sizeof-work-the-same-as)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to the answer provided by @ACB, you can use a `std::array`.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t S>
void foo(std::array<std::string, S> &bar) {
    for (auto &i : bar) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::array<std::string, 3> baz = {"hello", "world", "wooble"};

    foo(baz);

    return 0;
}
```

We could even use the template to allow for `std::array`s of other types. As long as there is an applicable `<<` overload with `std::ostream` and `T`.

```
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, std::size_t S>
void foo(std::array<T, S> &bar) {
    for (auto &i : bar) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::array<std::string, 3> baz = {"hello", "world", "wooble"};

    foo(baz);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::array<std::string, 3> baz = {"hello", "world", "wooble"};` that code means the array only has 3 items right?, how about if we don't know the array length? should I write `std::array<std::string> baz = {}` , because the array length depending from user input

Comment: With `std::array` you _must_ know the size at compiletime. If you will not know at compile time, use a `std::vector`.

Comment: Okay Thanks @Chris

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass it in as

```
void showData(string* data, size_t len);
```

but since you are using c++ its better to use something like [vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of C arrays. A different approach would be to use a template to deduce the size like this:

```
template<size_t S>
void showData(string (&data)[S]);
```

this gives you the size of the array as `S`

Comment: Okee Thankyou @ACB I'll try it, but how about when I call the function like this `showData(namaMahasiswa);` is that correct?

Comment: for that you can either use the template version or use a vector instead. The pointer version you have to call as `showData(namaMahasiswa, sizeof(namaMahasiswa));`

Comment: Okay thanks @ACB