# C++ sizeof different result for the same value

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I want to calculate the 'sizeof' array:

```
char* arr[] = { "abc", "def" };
```

When I call `sizeof` manually, immediately after the initialization of the array, it works fine. However if I pass the array to some function, It doesn't give the same result.

```
int test(char* b[]) {
    return (int)sizeof(b);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char* arr[] = { "abc", "def" };
    int p = test(arr); // gives 4
    int k = sizeof(arr); // gives 8
    ...
}
```

So what's the problem? Sorry for the newbie question, but I really miss it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sizeof array passed as parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328223/sizeof-array-passed-as-parameter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `sizeof` on `arr` in `_tmain`, you're taking the size of the array itself, which is `2 * sizeof(char*) = 2 * 4 = 8` on your architecture, because your `char*`s occupy `32` bits = `4` bytes.

When you use `sizeof` on `b` in `test`, you're taking the size of a pointer to the first element of the array, which is `sizeof(char**) = 4` on your architecture. The reason you're taking the size of the pointer and not the array is that you can't pass arrays as such to functions - instead, you pass them via a pointer to their first element. The information about the actual size of the array is thus lost in the call. Put another way, the signature of your function `test` is equivalent to `int test(char **b)`.

Comment: Thank you very much sir for a brief explanation. I appreciate all the other answers as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is because when you call a function in C or C++, [arrays decay to pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying).

In the first case, the compiler sees `arr` as an array; in the second case, all it sees is a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

At point where test is defined, compiler cannot see what b points to. So, sizeof gives the size of a pointer (actually, size of a pointer to pointers).

Inside main, it can see perfectly well that real size is two pointers.

There really is no such thing as passing array into function - only pointer to array is passed. The [] form is just syntactic sugar.

Comment: More like pollution than sugar.

Answer (score 0):

You lose the size information when calling `test` because you array decays to a pointer.

You have to pass the size of the array as additional parameter, or fix it in the parameter type.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to C++.

You cannot pass an array to a function at all. In C++, arrays decay to pointers most of the time. You are trying to pass an array but in fact passing a pointer, and your second `sizeof` evaluates to the size of that pointer.

You should not care about any of this. Arrays are specialized low-level data structures that should be only used to implement higher-level abstractions. Use `std::vector` instead.