# Size of an array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, size

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sizeof array passed as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328223/sizeof-array-passed-as-parameter)

I was wondering why the output of the following code is 1 and 9. Is that because of undeclared array in function size? How can I separate "size of array" to a function?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int size(int a[])
{
    return sizeof a/sizeof a[0];
}

int main()
{   
    int a[] = {5,2,4,7,1,8,9,10,6};
    cout << size(a) << endl;
    cout << sizeof a/sizeof a[0] << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: when you write `size(a)` then you're passing a pointer and not an array. Since the size of a pointer and an int is the same, you get 1/1 which is 1.

Comment: maroun post it as an answer. because it is one.

Comment: @Maroun85 Why a comment ? This is a valid answer.

Answer (score 13):

When you write `size(a)` then you're passing a pointer and not an array. Since the size of a pointer and an `int` is 4 or 8 (depending on ABI), you get `sizeof(int *)/sizeof int` (**4/4=1** for 32-bit machines and **8/4=2** for 64-bit ones) which is **1** or **2**.

In C++ when pass an array as an argument to a function, actually you're passing a pointer to an array.

Comment: The question is also "How can I separate "size of array" to a function?"

Comment: @downvoter, any comment please?

Comment: @MarounMaroun No, most downvoters are dumb. :P

Answer (score 8):

Maroun85 answer is correct. This is not obvious but `a` in `int size(int a[])` is a pointer.

But why don't you do it the c++ way. Using `std::vector`s

```
std::vector<int> a = {5,2,4,7,1,8,9,10,6};
cout << a.size() << endl;
```

no tricks here

-- edit

If your compiler does not support c++11. You can do:

```
std::vector<int> a;
a.push(5);
a.push(2);
...
cout << a.size() << endl;
```

Comment: +1 for answering the question "How to separate size()".

Comment: When I declare vector <int> a = {5,2,4,7,1,8,9,10,6};
the compiler warns that `a' must be initialized by constructor, not by `{...}'. Pls fix this for me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Your `size()` function cannot work like you want it to because when you pass an array to a function, the array decays to a pointer to its first element. Your `a` decays to a `int*` and sizeof operator on a pointer returns the size of the pointer, not the array. Consider using a `std::vector<int>` instead as this will allow you to retrieve the size of the vector each time you pass it to the function.

Comment: @downvoter Is there something incorrect in the my answer?

Comment: No there are some hobbiest downvoters.

Answer (score 5):

When passing arrays to functions, they decay to pointers. So, your `size()` function is equivalent to:

```
int size(int* a)
{
    return sizeof a/sizeof a[0];
}
```

And `sizeof a` is the size of a pointer, which is the same as the size of an int here, hence the output.

Answer (score 4):

Remember that array are always passed by pointer.

So in the function `a` is a pointer to `int`, and (for 32bit-intergers) the size of a pointer to `int` is the same of the size of an `int`.

Answer (score 4):

`sizeof` is evaluated at compile time, not at runtime. The compiler does not analyse what you pass to function `size`, but rather treats the function parameter as a pointer. Thus in your function `size` the result of `sizeof a` is the size of a *pointer* to an `int`, which is, by chance, equal to the size of an `int` on your system.

Answer (score 4):

The best explanation why your solution does not work is in Maroun's answer.

About the second part of the question ("how can it be done?"), you can do this with a template function:

```
template <typename T, size_t n> const size_t size(const T (&)[n]) { return n; }
```

Of course, this works only if the size of the array is constant (constant, as seen by the compiler), but it can only ever work in this case anyway -- an array does not store its size anywhere, so if it's not a known compile-time constant, there is no way to know it.

If you need this to work with arrays that are *not* compile-time constants (say, something you allocate with `operator new[]`, or using a non-standard compiler extension), you need to explicitly store the size somewhere.

(Incidentially, my above statement is *technically* wrong, indeed the allocation size is usually stored, but this is an implementation detail which you cannot and should not depend on.)