# c++ sizeof return wrong value of an array

Tags: c++, linux, windows, oop

I am learning c++ in school and we use linux ubuntu... we are learning oops and in oops we are doing classes right now.

I have two files, main file is called data.cpp and another  is called mylib.h

my data.cpp file has this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include "mylib.h"
int main() {

    myclass myfile;int i,b=14;// if i change this value its give always me value for 8 in windows and in ubuntu 4
    int arr[b];

//for(int i =0;i<b;i++){cout<<"Inserici Il numero : ";cin>>arr[i];}

    i = myfile.trovaMax(arr);
    cout <<"Arry Size "<<i<<endl;
    cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

mylib.h file contain this code:

```
class myclass{
  public:
    int trovaMax (int num[]){
     int curMax=sizeof(num);
/*         for (int i = 0; i<sizeof(num);i++){
           for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
              if(curMax<num[j]){
                  curMax=num[j];
              }//end if cond
           }//end for j loop
        }//end for i loop
*/       return curMax;
    }

   /* int findMinNum (int num[]){
      int curMax=99999;
        for (int i = 0; i<sizeof(num);i++){
           for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
              if(curMax>num[j]){
                  curMax=num[j];
              }//end if cond
           }//end for j loop
        }//end for i loop
       return curMax;
    }

};
```

**Problem:**
sizeof is give false value of an array that i pass in trovaMax funtion. In **windows** gives me always value 8 (if i change value of integer b in data.cpp file) And In **linux** always gives me value 4.

Now i am using windows at home.The program i am using is dev c++.

Note: I find this question, i did not find anywhere answer of this question.

Comment: It's totally a duplicate.

Comment: oops  yes it is..  but i didnt find this qustion  one i find .... i could not find

Comment: but that question is not using integer, i am using integer

Comment: The underlying type of the array is not material to the question. The same idea applies to every type.

Comment: i ask why it is retruning value 8 in window and 4 in ubuntu

Comment: @Phoenix: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13490665/4595816

Comment: why can not pass an array and what the hack is the pointer..?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointers.htm and http://stackoverflow.com/a/5159098/4595816

Comment: The duplicate question will explain to you that you are measuring the size of a pointer. The sizes of pointers are platform-dependent, so you may see different values on different platforms, but none of that changes the fact that you're only looking at a pointer, not at any kind of array.

Answer (score 1):

What you are passing to a function is not an array. You are passing it a pointer.

Comment: i dont know what is a pointer...  we have not done yet. According to me, i am passing an arry of value of b.

Comment: @Phoenix: Well, you are wrong.

Comment: so explain me... sir

Comment: What the other comments aren't explaining is this: you are seeing not the difference between Windows and Linux specifically, but the difference between a 64-bit operating system and a 32-bit one. In 64-bits systems, sizes of pointers are 8 bytes long, in 32-bits systems, 4 bytes. That is the result you're getting. Look it up.