# sizeof returns wrong value if argument is passed via function

Tags: c++, sizeof

Let me ask my question by this test program:

```
#include <iostream>

void testSizeOf(char* buf, int expected) {
    std::cout << "buf sizeof " << sizeof(buf) << " expected " << expected << std::endl;
}


int main ()
{
    char buf[80];
    testSizeOf(buf, sizeof(buf));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 buf sizeof 8 expected 80
```

Why do I receve `8` instead of `80`?

**upd** just found similar question [When a function has a specific-size array parameter, why is it replaced with a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328223/sizeof-array-passed-as-parameter?rq=1)

Comment: Pointers! OP's nick says it all.

Comment: Don't use pointers, don't use arrays, use `std::string`, `std::vector`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're taking the size of a `char*`, not of an array of 80 characters.

Once it's decayed to a pointer, it's no longer seen as an array of 80 characters in testSizeOf. It's seen just as a normal `char*`.

As for a possible reason why, consider this code:

```
char* ch = new char[42];
testSizeOf(ch, 42);
```

Would you expect sizeof to magically work there?