# Why does the length function return 2?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have written a function `size` which takes integer array as an argument.

```
int length(int a[])
{

    return  sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);

}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1,3,5,6,9,4,2,1,0,0};

    int len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);

    cout << len;  // This correctly prints 10 .

    len =  size(a);

    cout << len;  // But this print 2 .why ??

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain me this behaviour?
Thanks.

Comment: `int length(int a[])` is the same as `int length(int* a)`. Don't use that notation since, as you can see, it is misleading.

Comment: This *will* explain it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c

Comment: @0x499602D2 The opposite. It's twice the size of int

Comment: @0x499602D2 64-bit pointers.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan not necessarily. Could very well be a 64bit system with 64bit pointer, 32bit int. Or maybe 60bit pointer, 30bit int, 10bit char. You can just tell the ratio pointer/int, nothing else

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Can you explain me why it is  misleading ? I am not able to understand.

Comment: Inside main, compiler knows what `a` is. In the `length` function, it doesnt, because it is just a pointer parameter.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Why 64-bit? That's likely but not definite

Comment: @Thinker well, do the results match what you expected?

Comment: No the result does not match what i expected

Comment: Then what else do you need me to explain to show it is misleading? It (wrongly) lead you to think you are passing an array, and then you drew the wrong conclusions because you are actually passing a pointer.

Comment: @Thinker, there's a [good explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1328246/2417578) of what's going on in the first of the links that this question duplicates.  Arrays as function arguments work differently from your expectations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you get 2 is because `sizeof(int *)` is twice as large as `sizeof(int)`, and arrays decay into pointers when passed into a function.

There are various ways to work around this. In C++, you could use a `std::vector<int> a = { ... };` instead, which would solve the problem (by calling the `a.size()` to get the size, as `sizeof(a)` wouldn't work).

Comment: Or pass the array as `int (&)[N]`

Comment: @Mats can you give me some link regarding std:vector tutorial. I have no idea about that

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/
Not quite a tutorial, but perhaps a starting point. I'm sure google with "tutorial C++ vector" may give you some other links that at least some may be good - I haven't been "learning" about C++ (at that level at least), so not sure where a good tutorial site is.

Comment: @Thinker you should use a good beginners' C++ textbook. Things like `std::vector` are the very basic building blocks of the standard library as part of the language. It's a bread-and-butter `feature` like `double`, for-loops and the like.

Answer (score 0):

Because `sizeof(a)` is returning the size of the pointer which will be either 4 bytes or 8 bytes depending upon whether your app is 32-bit or 64-bit. So you would need to maintain the length of your array using a separate variable.

Or, better still, I would recommend using one of the standard collection classes, like `std::vector` for example since this will maintain the length automatically.