# Passing array of size 9 and becomes size 1

Tags: c++, arrays

simple call by reference

```
void foo(int* A)
{
    // ...
}

void main()
{
    int A[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
    foo(A);
}
```

not sure why but it is lessening the size of the array and losing/leaking information on the array....

Comment: Use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and save your self the pain. P.S: sizeof inside foo will give you the size of the pointer, because it's evaluated at compile time (it couldn't know what the pointer is pointing to).

Comment: re "simple call by reference", **no** it's not. it's call by value, passing a pointer. re `void main`, **no** that's not valid c++ (or c, for that matter). re "lessening the size", no, only apparently, but this so called **decay** is a heritage from C that's quite problematic.

Comment: Note for [tag:c++] _'call by reference '_ would literally mean `void foo(int &A[])`

Comment: `void main()` is incorrect; the correct declaration is `int main(void)`. Please discard whatever textbook told you to use `void main()`; its author doesn't know the language very well.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `void foo(int &A[])` is illegal C++, you probably meant `void foo(int (&A)[9])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should totally drop C-style arrays and use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead. Just compare this (which is the solution to your problem):

```
void foo(int* A, std::size_t size) {
    // ...
}

int main() {
    int A[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
    foo(A, (sizeof(A) / sizeof(int)));
}
```

to:

```
template<std::size_t Size>
void foo(const std::array<int, Size>& array) {
    // ...
}

int main() {
    std::array<int, 9> A {{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }};
    foo(A);
}
```

Ain't it beautiful? Or just take a look at how gorgeous it is with [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
void foo(const std::vector<int>& vector) {
    // vector.size() is the size
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> A = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
    foo(A);
}
```

And if you really want `foo` to be a generic algorithm, I'll just blow your mind with *iterators*:

```
template<class Iterator>
void foo(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    // ...
}

int main() {
    std::array<int, 9> A {{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }};
    std::vector<int> B = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
    foo(A.begin(), A.end());    // not a single problem
    foo(B.begin(), B.end());    // was given that day
}
```

C++ has an amazing (arguably) standard library and an amazing type system (if you don't overlook C legacy "features", like `void*`): use them.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing a pointer to the first element of an array. Create your function with the prototype

void foo(int* A, int size);

You will still be able to access A[0...size-1] like normal.

Answer (score 1):

> not sure why but it is lessening the size of the array and losing/leaking information on the array....

In `foo()`, `sizeof(A) == 8` not because it is "leaking" information, but because 8 is the size of the pointer of type `int*`. This is true regardless of how many integers `A` was initialized with in `main()`.

This may shine some light on what is happening:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void foo(int* A)
{
  cout << "foo: " << sizeof(A) << endl; // 8
}

void bar(int A[])
{
  cout << "bar: " << sizeof(A) << endl; // still 8
}

int main()
{
  int A[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
  cout << "main: " << sizeof(A) << endl; // 36 (=4*9)
  foo(A);
  bar(A);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
main: 36
foo: 8
bar: 8
```

In `main`, `sizeof` "knows" the size of `A[]` - it is sizeof(int) * length = 4 * 9 = 36. This information is lost when `A[]` is cast to a pointer `A*` in `foo`.

What if we pass in `A` as `bar(int A[])` instead. Will that retain the array length? No! In that case, `sizeof(A)` is still 8, the size of the pointer. Only in `main` does the compiler retain the information of array size of `A`.

If you want your functions to know the size of the array, use the `std::vector<int>` template, or pass in the size separately.

Here's another discussion on this: [When a function has a specific-size array parameter, why is it replaced with a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328223/sizeof-array-passed-as-parameter?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to pass array by reference is

```
void foo(int (&A) [9])
{
    // sizeof(A) == sizeof(int) * 9
}
```

the generic way is so:

```
template <std::size_t N>
void foo(int (&A) [N])
{
    // sizeof(A) == sizeof(int) * N
}
```

You may use `std::array` (C++11 required) which has a syntax more intuitive

```
template <std::size_t N>
void foo(std::array<int, N> &A)
{
    // A.size() == N
}
```