# how to loop through array using pointer without known the size of the array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a question about loop through array using pointer, for example:

```
bool loopArray(int* array)
{
   /*for(){}*/
}
```

within this function, I need to loop through this array without known the size of the array, how to loop it?

Comment: It can be done by using a sentinel value, such as a `char` array has when used as a string. For example, -1 when all other values will be positive.

Comment: You have 2 options: Either your data contains special value which you can test for, or you pass array size as an additional parameter. Use latter, it's more sane option.

Comment: It can be possible if the last value in the array is used to signal the end of the array. This is similar to strings in C,i.e,they end with a `\0` which marks the end of the string.

Comment: please note, defining a pointer witha a name `array` does not make it an `array`. it ___is___ a pointer. No `sizeof()`, sorry. It'll only return size of the pointer itself.

Comment: you loop as far as you want. If you get a segfault you know you went too far.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328223/sizeof-array-passed-as-parameter

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

Errrm, that's it.

You either provide a size parameter:

```
bool loopArray(int* array,size_t sz)
{
   for(size_t i=0;i<sz;++i){
       //Do stuff with array[i]....
   }   
}
```

Or a pointer to the 'end' of the array. You're allowed to point to one past the end and convention is to pass one-past-the-end as end. That allows you to specify 'empty' when `begin==end`:

```
bool loopArray(int* array,int* end)
{
   for(;array!=end;++array){
       //Do stuff with *array....
   }   
}
```

Looking at the previous example you would have defined `int* end=array+sz` before calling.

The second is faster and has the added benefit that other C programmers will start to recognize you as one of their own! If you see that as a benefit....

PS: For completeness: You can ensure you have a 'sentinel'. A sentinel is some value that indicates 'end'. The C standard library uses `'\0'` as the sentinel in character strings. Mores the pity.
That trick can work particularly when you're dealing with arrays of pointers and use `NULL` as the sentinel. 
However it's not something to recommend as a general answer. It's error-prone, has a big overhead if you need to know the size, it restricts your ability to access 'sub-arrays' without modifying them and forbids you from using the sentinel as a value and breaks programs that do so by accident. 
Other than that it's great.

Comment: Plus one to you too. Let's test the robustness of the sockpuppet checker...

Answer (score 3):

**it is impossible.** You need some kind of information about the size; otherwise you will inevitabilly go past its borders...

A pointer doesn't "contain" any information about the size of the array that was allocated; it only points to a place in memory.

**EXCEPT**
There might be a way around; if you know what is the last element in your array (which MUST always be present then). This is used for example in char arrays (where the last element is `\0`)

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

But you could do something on the lines of how the C standard library models strings. Given a `char*`, or a `const char*`, functions like `strlen` stop once 0 is reached (known as the null terminator).

So (i) either reserve an `int` value which acts as your terminator, or (ii) pass the length.

Either way, pass a `const int*` if you don't intend to modify the contents.

Comment: Up voted for same opening line!