# c++ gets different array length when passing the array as a arguments to a fucntion

Tags: c++, arrays, sizeof

In the below simple c++ program, I'm trying to get the length of an array by using `sizeof`, for same array, why when passing the array as an argument to a function the array length becomes incorrect? How should I get the length of an array who is an argument of a function?

```
#include <iostream>

int get_length(int arr[]){
  return sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);
}

int main(){
  int arr[] = {5,10,15,20};
  std::cout << "non function call: " << sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "function call: " << get_length(arr) << std::endl;
}
```

running result:

```
non function call: 4
function call: 2
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328223/sizeof-array-passed-as-parameter?rq=1

Comment: @David: No, not really, but it'll do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when passing the array as an argument to a function the array length becomes incorrect?

Despite appearances, the function parameter is a pointer (to the first array element), not an array. You get the ratio of the size of a pointer to the size of `int`, which happens to be 2 on your platform.

There's no way to determine the size of an array given just a pointer.

> How should I get the length of an array who is an argument of a function?

Arrays can't be passed by value to a function, and only arrays of known size can be passed by reference. So you'll need a template to infer the size of any array from the function argument:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
size_t get_length(T (&)[N]) {return N;}
```

In C++14 or later, this function is available in the standard library, and is called `std::size`. It's overloaded to work for both arrays and STL-style containers with a `size` member function.

Alternatively, you might consider using `std::array` (or `std::vector` when you need a dynamic/resizable array), rather than a quirky built-in array.

Comment: Mike you might want to change `get the ration of the size` to `get the ratio of the size`.  It wont let me edit it since it needs to be at least 6 characters.

Comment: Yeah I am not sure why it wont let me fix a simple typo.  Maybe I don't have enough rep to do that.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Yes, that's correct. Your edit would have to be a "suggested edit" due to your low rep, and those are required to be substantial to avoid bloating the review queues. You did the right thing here; thank you!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: No problem.  It tripped me up when reading the answer so I wanted to make sure it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass array to a function, the array decay to a pointer, so when you do `sizeof(arr)` in the function, you are asking the size of a pointer.

To make sure it doesn't decay, do it like this:

```
int get_length(int (&arr)[4]){
...
}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c) question for more about arrays.

If you want to pass an array that can be any size, use a std::vector.