# Reversing char array in C programming

Tags: c, arrays, char, reverse

I am new to c programming language. I am trying to reverse elements in char array. Actually, I almost reversed but there is something that I can't make it.
Here is code:

```
void q2_reverseTheArray(char word[100]){
int lentgh=sizeof(word);
int j;
for(j=length+1; j>=0; j--){
    printf("%c", word[j]);
}
```

The code reverse the array but it adds another letter.

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you're using? This shouldn't compile, as you have a typo in the declaration of `length`; then it should crash because you start the loop by accessing `word[length + 1]` which is 2 indices out of range.

Comment: Your for loop conditions are wrong. Arrays are indexed from 0 to length-1. Try the following: `for (j=length-1; j>0; j--)` This will start at the last character and repeat until the first one. Better yet, become accustomed to using your debugger.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I gave parameter "book". And the output was "aakoob".

Comment: To all readers: Having said "I am new to c programming language", cut this dude some slack and refrain from down-voting or close-voting the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sizeof array passed as parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328223/sizeof-array-passed-as-parameter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here you have a working example:

```
#include <stdio.h> // printf
#include <stdlib.h> // malloc, free
#include <string.h> // strlen

int main() {
  char* s = "hello";
  size_t l = strlen(s);
  char* r = (char*)malloc((l + 1) * sizeof(char));
  r[l] = '\0';
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    r[i] = s[l - 1 - i];
  }
  printf("normal: %s\n", s);
  printf("reverse: %s\n", r);
  free(r);
}
```

your code was wrong in `length + 1` it should say `length - 1`.

and you have to pay attention to the terminating `'\0'`.

Comment: Thank you ! I solved the problem by counting each element for finding length.

Comment: @Sahin could you please accept (_and maybe upvote ;-)_) an answer, so that the question appears answered. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The correct code is

```
for(j=length-1; j>=0; j--){
   printf("%c", word[j]);
```

This is because the string's elements are indexed from `0` to `length-1`. For example,

```
word == "Hello"
length == 5
word[0] == 'H'
word[1] == 'e'
word[2] == 'l'
word[3] == 'l'
word[4] == 'o'
```

Comment: I tried this but when I give the word[100]={"Look at Sky"}. It didn't reverse.

Comment: @Sahin try `strcpy(word, "Look at Sky"}` instead

Answer (score 0):

> Without string.h header file

```
main()
{
    char str1[100], str2[100];
    int i, k, j;
    scanf("%s", &str1);
    for(i=0; str1[i] != '\0'; i++ );
    j=i-1;
    for(k=0; k<=i; k++)
    {
        str2[k]=str1[j];
        j--;
    }
    for(k=0; k<i; k++)
        printf("%c", str2[k]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, using `strlen()` instead of `sizeof()` is better as it removes the need to modify the result in any way, like in my example:

```
char *c;
int i;
scanf("%s", c);
for (i = strlen(c); i >= 0; --i) {
  printf("%c", c[i]);
}
```