# C++ array as function parameter

Tags: c++

```
using Data = char[10];
void f(Data x)
{
    x = nullptr; // this compiles
}
void g(Data &x)
{
    x = nullptr; // this does not compile, msvc complain "expression must be a modifiable lvalue
}
```

I am confused why the assignment expression in f compiles, but does not compile in g. I expect that both assignment will fail since array type is not modifiable.

Any reference to c++ standard will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When a function has a specific-size array parameter, why is it replaced with a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328223/when-a-function-has-a-specific-size-array-parameter-why-is-it-replaced-with-a-p)

Comment: Prefer using a `std::array` or `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 2):

This has everything to do with function parameter type adjustment ([[dcl.fct]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct#5)):

> After determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type
>   “array of T” or of function type T is adjusted to be “pointer to T”.

Since a type alias is equivalent to the type it names, in the first case the type is determined as `char[10]` and adjusted to `char*`. You can modify a pointer.

In the second case, you form a `char(&)[10]`. It's a reference to an array, and arrays cannot be assigned to, even via a reference.

Comment: So the standard acts different between type is "array of T" and type is "reference to array of T", I might just accept that although it seems weird to me...

Comment: @xdot - That array type pulled in from C *are* weird. I concur with the comment on your post. `std::array` is better for such things. It's an actual value type.