# Unable to pass multi-dimensional array to base class in g++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, arduino, g++

I am new to C++ but have many years in C#, so excuse me if you see C# style coding, I am trying to grasp the concept of pointers, dereference, handles, references, array parameters and I still have difficulties.

The following is for an atmel microcontroller compiled with g++ 11 (arduino).

I am trying to pass a two-dimensionnal fixed size array of unsigned int as a parameter for a constructor of a base class, but no matter how I try, I can't get it transfer the array content in the base class.  Here is the raw code, without the includes, only the essential.

In this exemple, the "Derived" constructor is called and I expect it to call the "DisplayDriver" constructor and pass the _colorTable array to it as a parameter. :

**DisplayDriver.hpp**

```
class DisplayDriver
{
public:
    DisplayDriver(const int xResolution, const int yResolution, const unsigned int colorTable[18][2]);
}
```

**Derived.hpp**

```
class Derived : public DisplayDriver
{
public:
    Derived(const int xResolution, const int yResolution);

private:
    const unsigned int _colorTable[18][2] =
    {
        {4, 2},
        {9, 31},
        ... // 16 other lines.
    }
}
```

**Derived.cpp**

```
Derived(const int xResolution, const int yResolution) : DisplayDriver(xResolution, yResolution, _colorTable)
{
    // Here, _colorTable[1][0] gives 9 and _colorTable[1][1] gives 31.  As expected.
}
```

**DisplayDriver.cpp**

```
DisplayDriver(const int xResolution, const int yResolution, const unsigned int colorTable[18][2])
{
    // Here, colorTable[1][0] return 0, not 9.
    // colorTable[1][1] return 0, not 31.
}
```

I tried many different parameter types for the array :

- unsigned int (*colorTable)[18][2]
- unsigned int colorTable[][2]
- unsigned int (&colorTable)[18][2]
- with or without "const"

Comment: Using a two dimensional `std::vector` or `std::array` would be simpler.

Comment: There is no such thing in arduino.  Except at the expense of precious memory.  I implement myself standard libraries only if there is no other way.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is nothing to do with types (which are correct). The issue is that you are using a data member in `Derived` in the constructor for `DisplayDriver`. When the `DisplayDriver` constructor is called the `Derived` object has *not been constructed yet*, so the values are garbage.

Simple solution is to make `_colorTable` static.

```
class Derived : public DisplayDriver
{
public:
    Derived(const int xResolution, const int yResolution);

private:
    static const unsigned int _colorTable[18][2];
};
```

and

```
const unsigned int Derived::_colorTable[18][2] =
{
    {4, 2},
    {9, 31},
    ...
};
```

Comment: I understand.  I thought _colorTable being in the hpp file of derived, is initialized before calling the constructor of base.  In other words, I thougt Derived constructor will be complete before callind base.  By making it static, _colorTable WILL BE initialized before all that.  Thanks.

Comment: If I make it static, I have a message (translated) "a member of type 'const unsigned int _colorTable[18][2]' can't have a class initializer".  I will look for that now.  Not easy...

Comment: @sbeaudoin You need to separate the declaration from the definition, see the code I posted.

Comment: @sbeaudoin The declaration goes in your header file, but the definition (where the values get initialised) must go in a cpp file.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did and it worked perfectly.  I must remember that the hpp file is not the one who is compiled and it is not the same thing as "partial class" in the C# world.  That's what I thought first.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, your problem is that your using `_colorTable` before it has been initialised. If you don't mind all instances `Derived` sharing a common `_colorTable` (which is what `static` in the context of a class declaration means) then making `_colorTable` static works.

If you however want each instance to have its own `_colorTable` then one way to get around your problem is to use the [base-from-member idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Base-from-Member). This idiom utilize the initialisation order of base classes. When a class has multiple base classes...:

```
class A {  };
class B {  };
class C {  };

class D : public A, public C, public virtual B {  }; // note virtual
```

...C++ says that the initialisation order is:

1. All virtual base classes in the order of declaration (left to
   right).
2. All non-virtual base classes in the order of declaration (left to
   right).

Therefore if you if create an instance of `D` then `D`'s base classes gets initialised in the following order: first `B`, then `A` and then `C`. If your just starting out (and perhaps more so if you're using C++ on microcontrollers) then you don't have have to worry about virtual base classes.

So in your case, using your knowledge of base class initialisation order, you can use the base-from-member idiom. Create a new class and move `_colorTable` from `Derived` to your new class:

```
// Derived.hpp

// namespace detail {

class DerivedDMembers 
{
protected:
  const unsigned int _colorTable[18][2] =
  {
    {4, 2},
    {9, 31},
    ... // 16 other lines.
  };
};

// } // namespace detail

// if you feel that DerivedDMembers is polluting your namespace
// you can put it in a namespace called "detail". there's nothing
// special about 'detail' other than that "internal details" by
// convention are put in it.
```

Have `Derived` derive from your new class (`DerivedDMembers`):

```
// Derived.hpp

// note how DerivedDMembers is listed before DisplayDriver, which
// is crucial
class Derived : protected DerivedDMembers, public DisplayDriver
{
public:
  Derived(const int xResolution, const int yResolution);

  // note, _colorTable is now in DerivedDMembers  
};
```

Now you can safely pass `_colorTable` to your base class `DisplayDriver`:

```
// Derived.cpp

Derived(const int xResolution, const int yResolution) : DisplayDriver(xResolution, yResolution, _colorTable) {  }
```

You don't have to explicitly call `DerivedDMembers`'s default constructor in `Derived`'s constructors initialiser list because if a base class constructor call is omitted its default constructor is implicitly called.

Now each instance of `Derived` has its own `_colorTable` and you can use `_colorTable` to initialise `DisplayDriver`.

Comment: Thank you for the precision and for explaining another route.  But there will be only one display attached, so only one color table.  I will keep what you wrote in mind in case I need it later.

Comment: No problem. Another thing about your code, which isn't related to your problem: In `DisplayDriver`'s constructor you take a `const unsigned int colorTable[18][2]`. With that signature it'll accept any array of size `[n][2]` (for `n` > 0). If you only want arrays of size `[18][2]` then one solution is to take a `const unsigned (&colorTable) [18][2]` instead; a _reference_ to an array. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328223/when-a-function-has-a-specific-size-array-parameter-why-is-it-replaced-with-a-p). Also, the type `unsigned` is the same type as `unsigned int`.

Comment: Really?  The compiler will not check the array size?  If will follow your suggestion concerning using a reference for the parameter.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the order of initialization:

`Derived instance;`

is expanded to:

1. Call to constructor `Derived::Derived()`
2. To construct derived class the base classes must be constructed first. So 
   `DisplayDriver(xResolution, yResolution, _colorTable)` is run.
3. All member variables are constructed with their constructors in order in which they were declared in the class. In this case you specified that `instance._colorTable` is initialized to that array.
4. Body of `Derived::Derived` is executed.

So, in 2. you are using an uninitialized variable which is undefined behaviour -
 it can contain anything. In your case the variable contains array of zeroes.

To fix this you can mark `_colorTable` `static`.

Also there's no need to use const for `int` as it is passed by value.

Comment: Concerning const, I don't really understand all the flavors of it yet, so I put it everywhere I can until it don't work...

Comment: @sbeaudoin Yes, it might not be intuitive at first especially in more complicated cases with pointers and such. Especially comming from C# background, but it is very useful feature. Regarding your function: the int is passed by value=by copy so the function cannot change the variable you pass to the function. Only thing it does is that you cannot change the value of the new temporary variable/parameter which will destroyed at the end of the function anyway.