# not able to identify why invalid conversion from char* to char coming in function call

Tags: c++, string, types, char

> error coming-error: invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char'
>   [-fpermissive]

```
cout<< par(s,n1,num1,word);
```

Why calling `par()` function in main causing `invalid conversion from char* to char?`

Tried a lot to find the reason myself. I am a beginner in c++. I don't find anything wrong in the par() function. I haven't done assignment mismatch anywhere in the function, well thinking that there may be an error due to arguments presented in function par()

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int par(char s[][80],int,int,char);
char* substr(char*,int,int);
int main()
{
  char s[][80]={{"this is rockstar"},{"I am rockstar"},{"the best one"},{"no one can dare"},{"rockstar rocks always"}};
  char word[80]={"rockstar"};
  int n1=5;
  int num1=0;
  cout<<par(s,n1,num1,word);
  return 0;
}
int par(char s[][80],int n1,int num1,char word[80])
{
  int k=0;
  int length_word=strlen(word);
  int t=0;
  char beg[80];
  while(t!=strlen(word))
  {
    beg[t]=word[t];
    t++;
  }
  beg[t]=" ";
  char end[80];
  char mid[80];
  mid[0]=' ';
  t=0;
  int l=1;
  while(t!=strlen(word))
  {
    mid[l]=word[t];
    l++;
    t++;
  }
  mid[l]=' ';
  t=0;
  l=1;
  end[0]=' ';
  while(t!=strlen(word))
  {
    end[l]=word[t];
    t++;
    l++;
  }

  char temp[80];
  while(k<n1-1)
  {
    int i=0;
    while(s[k][i]!='\0')
    {
      temp[i]=s[k][i];
      i++;
    }
    if(strcmp(substr(temp,1,strlen(word)+1),beg)==0)
    {
      num1+=1;
    }
    int tr;
    for(tr=2;tr<strlen(temp)-(strlen(word)+2);tr++)
    {
      if(strcmp(substr(temp,j,strlen(word)+2),mid)==0)
      {
        num1+=1;
      }
    }
    if(strcmp(substr(temp,strlen(temp)-strlen(word),strlen(word)+1),end)==0)
    {
      num1+=1;
    }
    k++;


  }
  return num1;
}
char* substr(char *s,int i, int j)
{
  int pos=i-1;
  static char res[80];
  int k=0;
  while(pos<=i+j-2)
  {
    res[k]=s[pos];
    pos++;
    k++;
  }
  return res;
}
```

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328223/when-a-function-has-a-specific-size-array-parameter-why-is-it-replaced-with-a-p

Comment: It will help if you list specifically which line you're getting the conversation error on as well.

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be with the declaration of `par()`:

```
int par(char s[][80],int,int,char);
```

Here the fourth parameter is `char`. However, inside the `main()` function on the line

```
cout<<par(s,n1,num1,word);
```

you pass word, which is declared as `char[80]`, and array easily decay to pointers in C++ and C. (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1328246/6710751 for an explanation of why that happens.) So basically, you are passing an `char[]` (or `char*`, a pointer to `char`), while the compiler expects only `char`.

Of course, the later implementation of `par()` after the `main()` method has the correct type for the 4th parameter, but the compiler does not know about that yet when looking at the code inside `main()`. To fix this, you have to adjust the declaration of `par()` to match the implementation:

```
int par(char s[][80],int n1,int num1,char word[80]);
```

**Bonus:**
Since this is C++ and not C, you should prefer `std::string` over C-style `char[]` for any strings. [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is easier to handle, always knows its [size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) (unlike an array of characters) and buffer overruns, memory leaks and the likes which are quite common in C-style string handling can be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

The 4th parameter in the declaration of method par() is of type `char`. The argument you pass in is `char word[80]`.

Comment: What? This is wrong in every way possible. The 4th parameter passed isn't type `char` it gets converted to `char *`. Also what type are you talking about `char word[80]`...

Comment: Well the function declaration doesn’t match the definition then

Comment: @samuelnj - what is the type of the 4th parameter in the function declaration?

Comment: Fair enough, I see what you’re trying to say so downvote removed. But I think you can clarify that it’s the function declaration so it’s helpful to the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the 4th parameter was the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the prototype of function **par** :

```
int par(char s[][80],int,int,char);
```

the 4th argument is of type **char**,  whereas in the function definition of **par** :

```
int par(char s[][80],int n1,int num1,char word[80])
{...}
```

the 4th parameter is an **aray of type char**. So that's the error right there. To fix this error you need to change the 4th parameter in function prototype from `char` to `char []`.

Also, in the body of function **par** you have this line of code right after first while `beg[t]=" "`, this is wrong because you are trying to assign a string literal when it should be a character literal.

---

In body of function **par** you have this line of code `if(strcmp(substr(temp,j,strlen(word)+2),mid)==0)` here variable **j** is undefined, another error.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, the 4th parameter was causing the problem.