# function parameter of array of T "decaying" to pointer to T?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

If I have a function...

```
void f(int x[3]) {}
```

...is this distinguishable from a function...

```
void f(int* x) {}
```

If not, where in the standard does it address this issue?

Clearly there are array-to-pointer standard conversions, but I don't think they apply here?

I seem to remember language which said something to this effect, but can't seem to find it.

```
$ cat t.cc
void f(int x[3]) {}

void f(int* x) {}

$ g++ t.cc
t.cc: In function ‘void f(int*)’:
t.cc:3:6: error: redefinition of ‘void f(int*)’
 void f(int* x) {}
      ^
t.cc:1:6: note: ‘void f(int*)’ previously defined here
 void f(int x[3]) {}
      ^
```

Comment: Woudln't you be able to answer your first question by compiling that?

Comment: @gsamaras: I'm pretty sure the first answer is no, I'm looking for the standard reference.

Comment: A rhetorical question then Tomazos..:) Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1462103/2411320) answer your 2nd question?

Comment: 8.3.5/5, 13.1/3.2 in N4140. Just search for "adjusted".

Comment: *"I'm looking for the standard reference"* Then I suggest tagging with `language-lawyer`.

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1328223 probably

Comment: Yeah, it's the same Q...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I have a function...
>
> ```
> void f(int x[3]) {}
> ```
>
> ...is this distinguishable from a function...
>
> ```
> void f(int* x) {}
> ```

No. Those declarations are equivalent.

Standard draft:

> [dcl.fct]
>
> The type of a function is determined using the following rules. The type of each parameter (including
> function parameter packs) is determined from its own decl-specifier-seq and declarator. After determining
> the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of T” or of function type T is adjusted to be
> “pointer to T”.  ...

This rule complements the array decaying rule. Array decaying allows calling a function with - apparently - an array argument, while this rule allows declaring a function with - apparently - an array argument, while actually what is passed is a pointer. These rules stem from the C heritage of the language. Same with function to pointer decaying.

Comment: `[dcl.fct]/5` : http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#5

Comment: @AndrewTomazos note that the numbering of § paragraphs often change between standard versions, which is why I avoid them in my anwers. Sometimes rules migrate under different named sections too, but that's more uncommon.

Answer (score 3):

From [[dcl.fct§5]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#5) (emphasis mine):

> The type of a function is determined using the following rules.
>   The type of each parameter (including function parameter packs) is determined from its own *decl-specifier-seq* and *declarator*.
>   **After determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of `T`” or of function type `T` is adjusted to be “pointer to `T`”**.

Comment: I was curious, so I checked the timestamps. On the second. DAMMIT indeed :)

Answer (score 2):

It's described in the specification of function declarators

> **[dcl.fct]**
>
> [5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct#5) [...] After determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of
>   type “array of T” or of function type T is adjusted to be “pointer to
>   T”. [...]

Comment: DAMMIT. -------

Comment: @Quentin - Hey, it was you who dubbed me a hash table once ;)