# I have a question about passing std::array into function

Tags: c++

I'm learning c ++ And the syntax of putting a `std::array` into the function confuses me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

void printArray(const std::array<int, 5> &n)
{
    std::cout << "length: " << n.size() << endl;

    for (int j = 0; j < n.size(); j++ )
    {
        cout << "n[" << j << "] = " << n[j] << endl;
    }

}

int main()
{

    array<int, 5> n = {1,2,3,4,5};

    printArray(n);

    return 0;
}
```

1. I want to ask about 'const', what role does it play and what effect does it have if not using it?
2. Why do we have to use &n while the name of an array is already pointer

Comment: `const` isn't strictly related to arrays, it's a keyword you put on things to mean they can't be modified. And an array is not a pointer, the `&` means it's a reference.

Comment: "*the name of an array is already pointer*" `std::array` does not work like an `int[5]` array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the argument you can do certain assumptions about the function.

```
void printArrayA(std::array<int, 5> n)
```

If I call `printArrayA` then the array I pass to it is copied, so the function can't do changes to the array I pass, but has an overhead of copying the array.

```
void printArrayB(std::array<int, 5> &n)
```

If I call `printArrayB` then the array I pass to it is **not** copied, the function could do changes on the array, or on the elements stored in the array.

```
void printArrayC(const std::array<int, 5> &n)
```

If I call `printArrayC` then the array I pass to it is **not** copied, and because it is `const` the function can't do any changes on that array or on its elements. (Well I, in theory, could cast away the `const`, but that's not something that should be done, a `const` should indicate the caller, that the object won't be changed)

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not only about 'std::vector', it is about 'const' and 'references'.

1. 'const' keywords means that you can call only 'const' method of that class, means that (assume that the used class is implemented correctly) you can't modify this class in that method.
2. '&' means that you pass the parameter by 'reference' and not by 'value', if you are not familiar with that difference you may want to read this: [Value vs. Reference](https://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/valuevsreference.php)

Answer (score 3):

```
void printArray(const std::array<int, 5> &n)
```

What this does is to allow you to pass in to the function an unchangeable (without const-casting it, anyway) *reference* to the `std::array`. The reference is a lot smaller than the array itself, typically just a pointer, and the `const` bit ensures the function does not attempt to change the underlying object.

It's usually used to ensure you don't copy "large" things where unnecessary, things like vectors, arrays or strings.

Answer (score 3):

In this case `const` means that `printArray` will not modify the object passed to it.

An `std::array` is not a C-style array (such ase `int a[10]`), so you are not passing a pointer, you are passing a reference to an `std::array` object.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, the name of a `std::array` does not decay to a pointer.  To convert to a pointer, you would call `.data()`.

Why do you want to pass by (`const`) reference, and why does a `foo[]`decay to a `foo* const` in many contexts?

You (practically) never want to copy arrays.  It takes a huge amount of time and memory.  You always want to pass them to a function by reference.  On top of that, most algorithms that work on arrays are supposed to work on arrays of any size.  (Brian Kernighan, the K in K&R, [particularly considered it a flaw in Pascal that the size of an array is part of its type.](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/bwk-on-pascal.html))  Therefore, back in the ’70s, the designers of C made a rule that passing an array to a function is the same as passing a pointer to its first element.

C++ stuck with that for the sake of backward compatibility: a lot of programmers compile C code in C++ compilers.  One famous pitfall is [trying to take the `sizeof` an array parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328223/when-a-function-has-a-specific-size-array-parameter-why-is-it-replaced-with-a-p) in C++.  Because array parameters decay to pointers, this gives you the size of a pointer.  In C++, you have the option of passing a `type (&name)[size]` instead; that is, passing a `type[size]` by reference.  This preserves the size as part of the type.  (C also got some new syntax in 1999 that never made it over to C++, including the ability to pass the size of an array parameter.)

In C++, a `std::array` has no special syntax and works like any other type.  You never want to copy an entire array that you aren’t going to modify.  You still want to pass arrays by reference, so you use the standard syntax for that: `&`.  Whenever you don’t need to modify a parameter, you declare it `const`.  This helps the compiler detect logic errors and, sometimes, optimize.