# How debug a program that uses loops and sorting?

Tags: c++

I have a problem, I try to sort tabs and display them. User inputs number of how many tabs he wants to sort, but the last tab is not displayed.

I am beginner. How can I find where I made an error?

I tried tracking n integer, it resets to 0 after sorting the last tab, probably sorting algorithm messes it up, but I don't know how.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void bsort(int tab[]) {
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(tab)-1; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<sizeof(tab)-1; j++) {
            if(tab[j] < tab[j+1]) swap(tab[j+1], tab[j]);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int t, n;
    cin >> t;
    for(int i=0; i<t; i++) {

        cin >> n;
        int tab[n];

        for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            cin >> tab[j];
        }

        bsort(tab);
        cout << n << endl;
        for(int k=0; k<n; k++) {
            cout << tab[k] << " ";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<sizeof(tab)-1; i++)` -- What is the value of `sizeof(tab)`?  It isn't what you think it is.  Also `int tab[n];` is not legal C++.

Comment: `cin >> n;  int tab[n];` is not standard c++, [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard), better use `std::vector`

Comment: Why are you writing your own sorting function? What's wrong with `std::sort`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When a function has a specific-size array parameter, why is it replaced with a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328223/when-a-function-has-a-specific-size-array-parameter-why-is-it-replaced-with-a-p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are always passed by pointer to functions and the "length" of that array is lost.  `sizeof` on an array parameter of the function will always return the size of a pointer (4 or 8 depending if your app is 32-bit or 64-bit).

Instead of this:

```
void bsort(int tab[]) {
```

This (with a few additional fixes and optimizations thrown in):

```
void bsort(int* tab, int length) {
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        for(int j=i+1; j<length; j++) { 
            if(tab[i] > tab[j]) {        // replace "<" with ">" if you want descending sort
               int temp = tab[i];
               tab[i] = tab[j];
               tab[j] = tab[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your main function, invoke with the length of that array;

```
bsort(tab, n);
```

Also, I suspect there are other optimizations you can make to your bsort function.

Comment: There are other bugs in OP's code than just the length

Comment: I know.  But he posted his code and I can give him 30 seconds of my time.

Comment: I'm just noting it in case they copy that in and see it doesn't work.

Comment: @LouFranco imho there is nothing wrong with going one step at a time. One could also mention how "evil" `using namespace std` is and other things, but that would just distract from the immediate issue

Comment: thanks, changing arguments of the function helped me