# How do you pass fixed sized initializer lists of initializer lists through function parameters in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, initializer-list

I am making a matrix class where I want users to be able to instantiate the matrix like so:

`Matrix<float, 2, 2> mat = { { 10, 20 }, { 30, 40 } };`

My Matrix class is defined like so:

```
template<typename T, unsigned int ROWS, unsigned int COLS>
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix(std::array<std::array<T, ROWS>, COLS> matrix)
    {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
};
```

However, when I try instantiating the matrix, as I did above, I get "could not convert" errors from the compiler. I don't want to use initializer lists because I want compile-time errors to be triggered if the user defines the matrix with the wrong order. Does anyone why this isn't working? and if so is there an alternative?

Comment: Issue is that `std::array` use aggregate initialization (so might have/require extra brace), but then you have ambiguous call with copy/move constructor :-/

Comment: Thanks @Jarod42, is there any way around it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work...

```
template<typename T, unsigned int ROWS, unsigned int COLS>
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix(const std::array<T, ROWS> (&matrix)[COLS]) {
        // ... 
    }
};

int main() {
    Matrix<float, 2, 2> mat = {{ { 10, 20 }, { 40, 40 } }};
}
```

Though the error message is quite bad when it fails, and it only fails if you provide too many rows or columns!... for the same reason that `std::array<int,3> a = {1,2};` is valid...

**Edit:**

```
Matrix(const T (&matrix)[COLS][ROWS]) {}
```

is also valid

Comment: Thanks @JakeSchmidt, this works well, the only thing is I don't understand how the syntax works because I tried using ```Matrix(const std::array<unsigned, ROWS>[COLS]& matrix)``` instead and it didn't work

Comment: @MaximV https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328223/when-a-function-has-a-specific-size-array-parameter-why-is-it-replaced-with-a-p

Comment: Also, might it be possible to pass a c++ array like: ```Matrix(T[COLS][ROWS] matrix)```?

Comment: @MaximV  I don't think so

Answer (score 2):

`std::array` only supports aggregate initialization. By using the `Matrix<float, 2, 2> mat = { ... };` syntax, you are requesting copy initialization, which `std::array` just rejects. Note that, by taking a `std::array<std::array<...>...>` as constructor parameter, you allow the following initialization syntax: `Matrix<float, 2, 2> mat{{ 10, 20, 30, 40 }};`.

Most likely, what you want is a [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) parameter.

If you want your class to act like a `std::array` but with two dimensions, you might as well do what implementations of `std::array` do, which is having no constructor and making the inner member public:

```
template<typename T, unsigned int ROWS, unsigned int COLS>
class Matrix
{
public:
    T elements_[ROWS][COLS];
};
```

Here is the implementation of stdlibc++ (gcc): https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/array#L93. Note the declaration of `_M_elems` is public (`array` is a `struct` here). This means that you could access `_M_elems` directly if you know you are using this specific implementation of the standard library, but it's also the only way to get [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) working.

It also means you allow the syntax `Matrix<float, 2, 2> mat2 = { 10, 20, 40, 40 };`.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/516379d578c09610)

Comment: as said earlier, the problem with std::initializer_list is that I want compile-time errors to be triggered if the matrix is not of the right order.

Comment: @MaximV I added another option you might be interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is that `std::array` uses aggregate initialization (so might have/require extra brace), but then you might have ambiguous call with copy/move constructor :-/

Following compiles:

```
template <std::size_t COLS, std::size_t ROWS>
struct Matrix
{
    Matrix(const std::array<std::array<float, COLS>, ROWS>&) {}
    //Matrix(const std::vector<std::vector<float>>&) {}
};

int main() {
    [[maybe_unused]]Matrix<3, 2> m1 = std::array{ std::array{1.f, 2.f, 3.f}, std::array{1.f, 2.f, 3.f}};
    [[maybe_unused]]Matrix<3, 2> m2 ({{ {{1.f, 2.f, 3.f}}, {{1.f, 2.f, 3.f}}}});
    //[[maybe_unused]]Matrix<3, 2> m3 ({ {1.f, 2.f, 3.f}, {1.f, 2.f, 3.f}}); // OK vector
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/FKL3fW)