# Unexpected String Behavior C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, printf, c-strings, function-definition

I'm learning C++ on my own and am reading the book "*C++ Crash Course*" which has the following exercise:

> 3-2. Add a read_from and a write_to function to Listing 3-6. These functions
> should read or write to upper or lower as appropriate. Perform bounds checking to prevent buffer overflows.

Listing 3-6 that it references looks like this:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(){

    char lower[] = "abc?e";
    char upper[] = "ABC?E";
    char* upper_ptr = upper;

    lower[3] = 'd';
    upper_ptr[3] = 'D';

    char letter_d = lower[3];
    char letter_D = upper_ptr[3];

    printf("lower: %s\nupper: %s\n", lower, upper);
}
```

The way I rewrote it is this:

```
char* write_to(char string[], int index, char replacement){
    if (sizeof(string) <= index){
        string[index] = replacement;
        return string;
    }
    return NULL;
};

char read_from(char string[], int index){
    if (sizeof(string) <= index){
        return string[index];
    }
    return NULL;
};

int main(){

    char lower[] = "abc?e";
    char upper[] = "ABC?E";
    char* upper_ptr = upper;

    lower[3] = 'd';
    upper_ptr[3] = 'D';

    char letter_d = lower[3];
    char letter_D = upper_ptr[3];

    printf("lower: %s\nupper: %s\n", lower, upper);

    char* changed_lower[] = {write_to(lower, 3, 's')};

    printf("changed lower: %s\nindex 3 of upper: %s\n",
        changed_lower, read_from(upper, 3));
```

The program runs, but gives me some warnings and the wrong outcome:

```
lower: abcde
upper: ABCDE
changed lower: 
index 3 of upper: (null)
```

I think the program *should* return something more like:

```
lower: abcde
upper: ABCDE
changed lower: abcse
index 3 of upper: D
```

Where am I going wrong?

Edit: I removed the warnings because people were hyper-fixating on those and not the real problem, which is that it doesn't give me the correct output.

Comment: Read this about the `sizeof` issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328223/when-a-function-has-a-specific-size-array-parameter-why-is-it-replaced-with-a-p

Comment: Despite the use of a `.cpp` file extension and a C++ compiler, this code could pretty much compile as is in C. A book that teaches C as if it were C++ does not strike me as a good book. You should really be using `std::string`, but if you must keep using arrays, keep in mind that an array as a function parameter is actually a pointer in disguise, and therefore `sizeof` will not return what you expect for those.  You should pass in the size as well in those cases, so it is not lost.

Comment: _"Where am I going wrong?"_ That's what your warnings are telling you.  Are you hinting that you don't understand what the warnings are telling you?

Comment: I haven't gotten to strings yet, I just used the varriable named string because the term is faimiliar to me

Comment: As pointed out, read about `sizeof`. It is a _compile time_ operator, it can not measure stuff at run time. If you insist on using *C* like code, use `strlen`.

Comment: strlen did make two of the warnings go away but those weren't my biggest concern. It still doesn't print what think it should.

Comment: The fact that you don't feel the warnings were an issue is a problem in itself. If instead of `if (sizeof(string) <= index){` you used the proper order of `if (index < sizeof(string)){` you could easily access outside the bounds of the arrays you're using. Some other advice is to choose a name other than `string` for your variables. If this code was actual C++ and you'd picked up the bad habit of `using namespace std;` you'd likely have some interesting and not easily comprehensible to a beginner errors to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

There are many errors.

For example this function declaration

```
char* write_to(char string[], int index, char replacement){
```

is equivalent to

```
char* write_to(char *string, int index, char replacement){
```

due to implicit adjusting the parameter having an array type to pointer to the array element type by the compiler.

So within the functions the expression

```
sizeof(string)
```

yields the size of a pointer instead of the size of the passed array.

Instead of the operator `sizeof` you need to use the standard C string function `strlen` declared in the header `<cstring>`.

Also it does not make a sense to return `NULL` from the both functions.

```
return NULL;
```

As the function `read_from` has the return type `char` then you may not use the conversion specifier `%s` with the function return value

```
printf("changed lower: %s\nindex 3 of upper: %s\n",
        changed_lower, read_from(upper, 3));
```

You need to use the conversion specifier `%c`.

Declaration of the variable `changed_lower` as having an array type

```
char* changed_lower[] = {write_to(lower, 3, 's')};
```

also does not make a great sense. You may not output it using the conversion specifier `%s`. At least if the variable has the array type you need to use the argument expression  `changed_lower[0]` in the call of `printf`.

Though it is better to declare just a pointer

```
char *changed_lower = write_to(lower, 3, 's');
```

The functions can be declared and defined the following way

```
#include <cstring>

char * write_to( char string[], size_t index, char replacement )
{
    if ( index < std::strlen( string ) )
    {
        string[index] = replacement;
    }

    return string;
}


char read_from( const char string[], size_t index )
{
    return index < std::strlen( string ) ? string[index] : '\0';
}
```

Pay attention to that the null declarations after the function declarations like this

```
char* write_to(char string[], int index, char replacement){
    //...
};
^^^
```

are redundant and should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
void func1() {
    char str[] = "abcde";
    func2(str);
    ...
}

void func2(char str[]) {
    ...
}
```

If `func1`, the value of `sizeof(str)` is equal to 6 (5 characters + the null character).

If `func2`, the value of `sizeof(str)` is equal to `sizeof(char*)`, i.e., the size of a memory pointer on your platform (typically 4 or 8 bytes, but can be any other value in theory).

When you call `func2(str)`, only a pointer to the beginning of the string is passed to the function, not the entire string.

Comment: But the variable can't be in the body of the function, because I need it to work on multiple items. I would need to pass it as a parameter, wouldn't I?

Comment: @SamL: The point is that you should not use `sizeof(string)` when `string` is passed to the function from somewhere else. Instead, you should use `strlen(string)+1`.

Comment: That does remove 2 of the warnings but doesn't change the behavior of the program, which is my primary question.