# How do I make an int that is the length of an array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, xcode

So basically I'm trying to write a method that returns two times the length of an array, but I cannot figure out how to make the length into an int so that it can be used.  I have been trying to figure out the correct method to use since sizeof() returns the number of bytes, not the length of the array.  What method should I be using and how can I fix this?  Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    cout << getLen(arr);
    return 0;
}

int getLen( int *arr ){
    int len = sizeof(arr);
    return 2 * len;
}
```

Comment: @melk That wont work since `arr` is a pointer, not an array in `getLen`

Comment: related/maybe dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062005/size-of-array-passed-to-c-function

Comment: [std::size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size)

Comment: Just use [`std::array<int, 5>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) that comes in with a `std::array::size()`

Comment: @NathanOliver, PeteBecker Right you are.

Answer (score 2):

I think this could be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Ultimately if you want this kind of behaviour in C++ you should use an std::vector object. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> // Remember to include this

int getLen(std::vector<int> &vec) // Pass vec by reference rather than as a pointer
{
    return static_cast<int>(vec.size()) * 2; // Use .size() to get the number of elements in vec
    // ^^^ .size() returns a value of type size_t which is converted to an int using static_cast<int>
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = {1,2,3,4,5};

    std::cout << getLen(vec);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good answer.  However, your code generates:  "warning: conversion from ‘std::vector<int>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} to ‘int’ may change value [-Wconversion] "   Trivial fix: You can use static_cast<int> to convert the size_t to int.

Comment: @2785528 Hmmm I didn't get a warning for that when compiling in Visual Studio 2019 but nevertheless I've edited the answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T,std::size_t n>
std::size_t get_new_len(T (&a)[n]) {
    return n*2;
}

int main() {
    int a[10] = {0};
    std::cout << get_new_len(a) << "\n";
}
```

you can do it in this way, using template argument deduction.
output is 20

Answer (score 0):

The result of `sizeof(arr)` is not the same in the main as in the function, i don't understand why , but it works like this :

```
int getLen(int *arr, int arrSize)
{
    int len = arrSize / sizeof(int);

    return len;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    cout << getLen(arr,sizeof(arr));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because the `arr` in your function is a pointer not an array.

Comment: But even when we pass `arr` as an array in the function (int arr[])  it'll give wrong results (sizeof(arr)=2)

Comment: When you use the syntax with the square brackets it's still a pointer.

Comment: So i understand from what you said that is impossible to get the correct array size inside the function ?

Comment: Yes. The only way would be to pass the size separately.