# Why is the code that works correctly in Main works incorrectly inside the function ? (C++)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find the length of an array with the code below, but when I'm trying to run it inside of a function, it doesn't work right.

```
int nums1 []={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
const int len1=sizeof(nums1)/sizeof(nums1[0]);
```

When I'm passing `nums1` to the function and then trying to find the length of `nums1`, same code doesn't work right.

This is my codes and what I get as a result:

[image]

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [size of array passed to C++ function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062005/size-of-array-passed-to-c-function)

Comment: I'm not an C++ coder. But shouldn't the input to your function be an array pointer, and not just an int pointer?

Comment: [Edit] the question to include the code _as text_, not an image. See [ask].

Comment: @Sandsten When an array is passed to a function it decays to a pointer. In this case an `int` array decays to an `int*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rewrite the two examples

```
const int len1 = sizeof(int[10]) / sizeof(int)
```

and

```
const int len2 = sizeof(int*) / sizeof(int);
```

The first one takes the size of an int *array*, whereas the second one takes the size of an int *pointer*. In your architecture, an int is 4 bytes long, and an array of 10 ints is therefore 40 bytes long. A pointer on the other side, takes 8 bytes on this architecture (most likely 64 bit).

Comment: thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The size of a pointer is something different than the size of an array, the pointer might point to. When you pass or assign an array to a pointer, it decays into a pointer to the first element. And the C++ programming language (just like C) has no implicit mechanism to convey the size across such decay.

You'll have to specify the number of elements explicitly as an additional parameter to the function. Or just use a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: I got it thanks a lot for your answer.