# Matrix size returns always 8

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

in the code below, I want to find the size of the 2d array(matrix), however, when I try to do that, eventhough I was declared the size of the matrix just before testing it, it always outputs 1. And size of the factorMatrix and factorMatrix[0] looks same as 8. Any idea what may be causing this? Thanks.

```
factorMatrix = new int* [3];
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        /**/
        factorMatrix[i] = new int [1];
    }   

factorCountMatrix = new int* [3];
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        /**/
        factorCountMatrix[i] = new int [1];
    }

factorMatrix[0][0] = 2;
factorCountMatrix[0][0]= 0;

factorMatrix[1][0] = 3;
factorCountMatrix[1][0]= 0;

factorMatrix[2][0] = 5;
factorCountMatrix[2][0]= 0;

//test = checkFactorMatrix(3);
test = (sizeof(factorCountMatrix) / sizeof(factorCountMatrix[0]));
cout <<  test << endl << endl;
```

Comment: factorCountMatrix and factorCountMatrix[0] are both pointers, so they have the same size

Comment: [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) tells you the size **of the type**, i.e. of `int*`

Comment: Weren't you given the same answer to a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624262/something-went-wrong-with-passing-pointer-to-a-function) two days ago?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `sizeof` operator on a pointer, you get the size of the pointer, and not what it points to. You need to keep track of the size of the memory you allocate yourself, or use something else like [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (which I recommend).