# How do i handle this situation C++ sizeof problem

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, sizeof, implicit-conversion

```
void f(int* b[])
{
    cout << sizeof(*b) << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int x[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int* a[] = {&x[0], &x[1], &x[2], &x[3]};

    cout << sizeof(a) << endl;

    f(a);
}
```

The program is output firstly 32 (in main)
and 8 (in function)

How do i handle this situation?

Comment: You must pass the size of the array into your function as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When passing an array to a function in C++, why won't sizeof() work the same as in the main function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36525798/when-passing-an-array-to-a-function-in-c-why-wont-sizeof-work-the-same-as)

Comment: The size of a pointer is the size of the pointer itself, not what it might point to (since the compiler doesn't really know what it might point to).

Comment: Also, if you wanted to really compare apples to apples, in `f` you should have done `sizeof(b)` and not `sizeof(b[0])` (which is what `sizeof(*b)` really is). Not that it would change anything, since `b` is also a pointer.

Comment: The parameter type `int* b[]` is equivalent to `int** b`, while the type of `a` is not `int*[]`, but `int*[4]`

Comment: You pass a pointer to an array, and the size of pointer on your platform is 8 bytes (apparently 64 bit platform). If you pass 'int b[const]', it would decay into a pointer as well, and its size would be 8 bytes as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood correctly you are trying to get the size of the passed array in the function.

Do it the following way

```
template <size_t N>
void f( int* ( &b )[N] )
{
    cout << sizeof( b ) << endl;
}
```

In C you should declare the function with one more parameter like

```
void f(int* b[], size_t n )
{
    printf( "%zu\n", n * sizeof( *b ) );
}
```

and call it like

```
f(a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) );
```

Such an approach you can use also in C++.

Comment: Better put the size arguments before the array pointer in C, as that allows you to use them to declare pointers to arrays: `smoothImage(int width, int height, Pixel image[height][width])` Or equivalently, declaring the pointer the way it's understood by the compiler: `smoothImage(int width, int height, Pixel (*image)[width])`

Comment: @cmasterThere is no variable length array. So your suggestion does not male sense in this situation.

Comment: There is. In C. Since C99. Not in C++, that language is vastly inferior to C99 in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

You handle the situation by passing the number of elements in the array using a `size_t` type.

Once the array is passed to a function, it *decays* to a pointer to the first element. All size information is lost. `sizeof` is a curious operator insofar that pointer decay doesn't apply to its argument, which accounts for the difference in output.

Answer (score 0):

Array decays to a pointer. That is the reason of the problem. Here's how you can solve it. Pass the array by reference:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T &b) {
  std::cout << sizeof(b) << std::endl;
}
```