# Trying to pass an array in a function, getting no instance of overload function error

Tags: c++, pointers

I am creating a custom Node class that holds a number and a pointer to another node. I am writing a function called AssignArray which takes an array and creates a linked list of nodes from the numbers in the array. I am passing an array to the AssignArray function, and need to remove the first element from the array with each new recursive call of the function. I am trying to do that by copying the initial array into a smaller array, and then passing the smaller array into the recursive call of the AssignArray function. I am getting an error when I try to copy the array. Here is my .hpp file:

```
class Node {

    Node* node;
    int num;

    public:
    Node(int new_num);
    void AssignNode(Node* new_end);
    Node* AssignArray(int list[]);

};
```

Here is my node class file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "node.hpp"

Node::Node(int new_num) {
    num = new_num;
}

void Node::AssignNode(Node* new_node) {
    node = new_node;
}

Node* Node::AssignArray(int list[]) {
    if (sizeof(list) == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {

        Node new_node(list[0]);
        int new_list[sizeof(list)-1];
        std::copy(1, std::end(list), std::begin(new_list));
        new_node.AssignNode(new_node.AssignArray(new_list));
        return &new_node;

    }

}
```

My IDE gives me an error which says "No instance of overloaded function "std::end" matches the argument list -- argument types are (int *)

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: `list` is a pointer

Comment: what did you expect `std::end(list)` to do?

Comment: actually the whole line `std::copy(1, std::end(list), std::begin(new_list));` does not make much sense. Review what `std::copy` is: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy

Comment: `sizeof(list)` is also not what you think it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36525798/when-passing-an-array-to-a-function-in-c-why-wont-sizeof-work-the-same-as