# toString for printing array is not working C++

Tags: c++, arrays, size, tostring

I have a `int array`. Size of this array is different is `main` and in `toString` method.

```
void toString(int arr[]){
    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    cout<<"Size in toString  "<<size<<endl;
    cout<<"{";
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<<", ";
    }
    cout<<"}"<<endl;
}

int main(){
    int input_arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int size_in_main = sizeof(input_arr)/sizeof(input_arr[0]);
    cout<<"Size in main      "<<size_in_main<<endl;
    toString(input_arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Size in main      4
Size in toString  2
{1, 2, }
```

Why is it print different array size?

Comment: Another possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/968112/1632887

Comment: Its C++, use std::array or std::vector!

Comment: @manni66 I am using `using namespace std;` in my code so i guess `std::array` is not required.

Comment: std::array != []. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer passed as an argument does not have size information. 
You have to add size as an argument.

Comment: But why is it always showing size 2. Why not some random number.?

Comment: I would have expected 1. No idea.

Comment: A possible explanation may be that : A pointer on a 64-bit system gets allocated 8 bytes and arr[0] will be of size 4 so 8/4=2.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, passing an array to a procedure or function call won't create a local copy of the data inside of the array, but rather provide a pointer to the array of data (pass by reference). Because of this, sizeof(arr) will return the size of 'int *', not 'int []'.

This can be resolved by adding a size parameter to your function or procedure that represents the size of the array like so.

```
void toString(int arr[], int arr_size){
    int size = arr_size/sizeof(arr[0]);
    cout<<"Size in toString  "<<size<<endl;
    cout<<"{";
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<<", ";
    }
    cout<<"}"<<endl;
}
```

Which could then be called like this

```
toString(input_arr, sizeof(input_arr));
```

Comment: You mean `int size = arr_size/sizeof(arr[0]);`

Comment: Just realised I pasted the wrong line - thanks