# How can I calculate size of Array in C++

Tags: c++

I had the online coding interview today and I really struggled while trying to calculate the size of the array. 
Could you please help me with how can I measure the sizeof array here? I tried my best but no luck please help here.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

void arraysize(int* a) {
    cout << "size1: "<<sizeof(a) << endl;
    cout << "size2: " << sizeof(a[0]) << endl;;
}

int main()
{
    int array1[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 }; 

    arraysize(array1);


    return 0;

}
```

Result:
size1: 4
size2: 4

Comment: Are you allowed to change `arraysize`'s signature? If so, if you make a template-function that accepts `std::array` then it's straightforward.

Comment: The function `arraysize` cannot determine the size of `array1` from the information available to it in the code shown. What was the specific question you were asked? If it was how to change the code to make the array size available, then there are several alternatives.

Comment: Helpful reading: [What is array to pointer decay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay)

Comment: Something to read https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=jXt0CwAAQBAJ&q=%22This%20cretinous%20barfbag%20uses%20sizeof%20to%20return%20the%20size%20of%20the%20array%22#v=snippet&q=%22This%20cretinous%20barfbag%20uses%20sizeof%20to%20return%20the%20size%20of%20the%20array%22&f=false

Comment: Does this answer your question? [determine size of array if passed to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968001/determine-size-of-array-if-passed-to-function)

Answer (score 3):

In most cases, when you pass an array to a function, the array will be converted to a pointer. This is called an *array-to-pointer decay*. Once this decay happens, you lose the size information of the array. That is, you can no longer tell the size of the original array from the pointer.

However, one case in which this conversion / decay will ***not*** happen is when we pass a **reference** to the array. We can take advantage of this property to get the size of an array.

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename T, size_t N>
size_t asize(T (&array)[N])
{
    return N;
}

int main()
{
    int array1[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };
    std::cout << asize(array1) << std::endl;  // 8
    return 0;
}
```

In the above case, to the template function `asize`, we pass a reference to an array of type `T[N]`, whose size is `N`. In this case, it is array type `int[8]`. So the function returns `N`, which is size 8.

Answer (score 0):

`C` style `array`'s decay to `pointer`'s when passed to a function like this.
The first `cout` statement is printing the size of a `pointer` on your machine.
The second `cout` statement is printing the size of an `integer`.

Use one of the following solutions in order to pass the size of the `array` to the function.

```
template<std::size_t N>
void ArraySize( int ( &array )[ N ] )
{
    std::cout << "Array size: " << N << '\n';
}

void ArraySize( int* array, std::size_t size )
{
    std::cout << "Array size: " << size << '\n';
}

template<std::size_t N>
void ArraySize( std::array<int, N>& array )
{
    std::cout << "Array size: "<< array.size( ) << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sizeof(a) returns the number of bytes in array,
sizeof(int) returns the number of bytes in an int,
ergo
sizeof(a)/sizeof(int) returns the array length

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to get the size of an array:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    int ch[5], size;

    size = sizeof(ch) / sizeof(ch[0]);

    cout << size;

    return 0;
}
```

> Output: 5

Answer (score 0):

simply divide `sizeof(array1)` by `sizeof(int)`. it will give you total element in array. because `sizeof(array1)` will give total bytes in the array. for example `sizeof(array1)` = int * 8 because your array is int so int is 4 byte answer is 4*8 = 32.Now you have to divide it again by 4 cause its in byte.

```
cout << "Size of the Array is : " << sizeof(array1)/sizeof(int) << endl;
```

put above code in your main function to get result