# Calculating the size of the array gives variable output

Tags: c++, pointers, c++14

I'm calculating the size of the array using following code

```
int  arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int size = *(&arr + 1) - arr;
```

This gives me 6 as output. However, when I create a function with the same code, the size becomes -8. What could be the reason for this behaviour.

```
int sizeArr(int arr[])
{
    int size = *(&arr + 1) - arr;
    return size;
}
```

Comment: dupe of [determine size of array if passed to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968001/determine-size-of-array-if-passed-to-function) and many others. research _array to pointer decay_, _array passing to function_, etc.

Comment: "*This gives me 6 as output*" That doesn't mean it's the size of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the way pointer arithmetic works.

An expression of the form

```
pointer + amount
```

is, informally speaking at least, evaluated as

```
pointer + sizeof(*pointer) * amount
```

In other words, pointer arithmetic adds `sizeof` units of the type.

In your first snippet, `sizeof(arr)` is the size of the actual array. But in the function, it's the size of the pointer to an element in the array due to *pointer decay*!

See for yourself - output `sizeof(arr)` in both cases, and note the difference.

(To add to the bewildering list of rules, the evaluation of `sizeof(arr)` is one of those instances where `arr` does **not** decay to a pointer type! Oh joy!)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> int sizeArr(int arr[])
> {
>     int size = *(&arr + 1) - arr;
>     return size;
> }
> ```

The `arr` parameter in the `sizeArr` function contains no size information (as compared to if you pass an array by reference to the function), and arguments passed to it will _decay to a pointer). Thus, the size you are attempting to calculate does some (mis-)calcuations based on a pointer, not on an object of array type.