# how to calculate number of elements in array passed in function

Tags: c++, arrays, function

why the number of elements in an array is calculate incorrect when passing an array to a function;
They don't work, but why, and what works without passing the quantity as a parameter.

```
int foo(int arr[])
{
   return         sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]
}

int foo2(int arr[])
{
 int len = 0;

 for(auto i: arr)

 {

 len++

 }
 return len;
 }
```

☝️This function dont return correct

Comment: Not possible. [The array has decayed to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/4581301), so `sizeof` is providing the size of the pointer. You need to pass in the size, use a smarter data structure that carries the size like `std::array` or `std::vector`, or define [a template function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/968001/4581301).

Comment: you can forget about `sizeof` to calcuate the size of an array. When you really have to determine the size of a c-array use `std::size`

Comment: Use `std::vector`.  A vector maintains its capacity.  You can pass it by reference or const reference.